# What does "--" (double-dash) mean?

Tags: shell, command-line, utilities, syntax

I have seen `--` used in the `compgen` command.

For example:

```
compgen -W "foo bar baz" -- b
```

What is the meaning of the `--` in there?

Answer (score 1001, accepted):

More precisely, a double dash (`--`) is used in most Bash [built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) commands and many other commands to signify the end of command options, after which only positional arguments are accepted.

Example use: Let's say you want to grep a file for the string `-v`. Normally `-v` will be considered the option to reverse the matching meaning (only show lines that do not match), but with `--` you can grep for the string `-v` like this:

```
grep -- -v file
```

Comment: Most notably in the Bash `set` built-in, where it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: `--` works to separate options from regular expressions in `grep`, but the canonical way is to use `-e`/`--regexp`.

Comment: @l0b0: the pattern to search is normally one of the positional parameters, so it can fit after the `--`, though you are correct in noting that my example above could also be written as `grep -e -v file` (although that is very confusing).

Comment: Not all `bash` builtin commands accept `--` as the end of option marker. `[` and `echo` don't for instance ([one of the reasons `echo` can't be used reliably](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)).

Comment: Should probably be "positional arguments" instead of "positional parameters". From [Parameter vs Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter): "parameter is part of the function/procedure/method signature and an argument is the actual value supplied"

Comment: @david-tonhofer - accepted though this answer is already scoring way too high for the actual value of provides... 

Comment: Do the commands need to implement double dash themselves or is it a bash thing?

Comment: @Ziyuan its a convention: each command that wants to support this convention needs to implement it. Luckily, its easy with the GNU libc `getopt()` function that has built-in support for that: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html

Comment: @Guss thanks, good to know.

Answer (score 86):

In `man bash` we can read in *Shell Builtin Commands* section ([online doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html)):

> Unless otherwise noted, each builtin command documented in this section as accepting options preceded by `-` accepts `--` **to signify the end of the options**.
>
> The `:`, `true`, `false`, and `test` builtins do not accept options and do not treat `--` specially.  The `exit`, `logout`, `break`, `continue`, `let`, and `shift` builtins accept and process arguments beginning with `-` without requiring `--`. Other builtins that accept arguments but are not specified as accepting options interpret arguments beginning with `-` as invalid options and require `--` to prevent this interpretation.
>
> Note that `echo` does not interpret `--` to mean the end of options.

Answer (score 59):

This marks end of parameter (option) list.

Answer (score 41):

> POSIX.1-2017
>
> 12.2 Utility Syntax Guidelines
>
> Guideline 10:
>
> The first `--` argument that is not an option-argument should be
>   accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following
>   arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the
>   '`-`' character.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02

Comment: This is the authoritative answer.

Answer (score 33):

In commands that use the [POSIX `getopt()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/getopt.html) API to parse options, as well as several others, `--` marks the end of options.

In:

```
rm -f -- -f
```

The first `-f` is taken as an option to `rm`, while the second is taken as the name of a file to remove as everything past `--` is not taken as an option.

In POSIX-compliant utilities and `getopt()` implementations, options are not accepted after non-option arguments, so for instance:

```
grep pattern -f
```

is required to look for lines matching `pattern` in the file called `-f`.

However, the GNU implementation of `getopt()` and its `getopt_long()` extension as used by most GNU utilities including GNU `grep` (but not `bash` nor any of its builtins even though `bash` is the GNU shell) doesn't do that by default unless there's a `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable in the environment.

So, for those, `--` is needed even if there are leading non-option arguments:

```
grep -- pattern -f
```

An older way to mark end of options was with `-`. You'll find that most `sh` implementations still support `-` as an end-of-option marker, as well as most of the builtins of ksh or zsh. That is however not common these days.

Some commands are known not to support `--` as the end of option marker. Most `echo` implementations are among those. That's [one of the reasons they can't be used to output arbitrary data](/q/65803).

## ⚠️ Important

That `--` is needed when non-option arguments start with `-` (or possibly `+` for some commands), but **also when you can't guarantee some non-option arguments won't start with `-`/`+`**. That includes:

- `rm -f -- "$file"`
- `rm -f -- "${files[@]}"`
- `rm -f -- *.txt`
- `rm -f -- $(command-that-generates-a-list-of-files-or-file-patterns)`
- `cmd | xargs rm -f --`

If you can't guarantee the command supports `--` as the end of option marker, for those arguments that are file names, another approach is to prefix the file name with `./`:

```
somegrep pattern ./*.txt
```

**Failing to add those `--` can introduce arbitrary command injection vulerabilities**, especially if you also [forget to quote your expansions](/q/171346). For instance:

```
sed -e 's/foo/bar/' *.txt
```

Will run `reboot` if there's a file called `'-es/.*/reboot/e;#.txt'` in the current working directory. Fixed by changing it to `sed -e 's/foo/bar/' -- *.txt` or `sed -e 's/foo/bar/' ./*.txt`.

Same for:

```
rename 's/foo/bar/' *foo*
```

with some `rename` variants; beware some (non-vulnerable) `rename` variants don't support `--`.

```
print $var
```

In `zsh` (even though leaving parameter expansions unquoted is relatively safe in that shell), will run reboot if `$var` contains `-va[1$(reboot)]`. Fixed with `print -- $var` or `print - $var` though you likely want `print -r -- $var` to also disable the backslash processing.

Comment: Could you link to the posix `getopt()` API? Else, really great answer, take my upvote!

Comment: @Junaga, I've added a link to the HTML version (so non-official) of the `getopt()` specification in the 2018 edition. The PDF one (official) is not publicly available, though you can register (for free) with the opengroup to obtain it for free.

Comment: thank you for your 'Important' remark. It answered my issue.