# How to move 100 files from a folder containing thousands?

Tags: files, mv

I have a directory with thousands of files. How can I move 100 of the files (any files will do) to another location.

Comment: Because Unix and Linux dont have one big website about its tools, so I simply go to website like `about.com` and some other website for the list of options available that I can possibly use.. but found nothing like `tail`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
for file in $(ls -p | grep -v / | tail -100)
do
mv $file /other/location
done
```

That assumes file names don't contain blanks, newline (assuming the default value of `$IFS`), wildcard characters (`?`, `*`, `[`) or start with `-`.

Comment: Note that this approach only works if there are no special characters (whitespace, nonprintable characters, ``) in the file names. As a general rule, [do not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). And always double-quote parameter and command substitutions.

Comment: Which part accounts for 100 files?

Comment: Update to my previous comment: After reading Gilles' reference link, [do not parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), I've found that my `find` command was lacking. An arg was in the wrong place, and I've added null file-name endings. It is a bit long of a single line, but that's all I can do in a comment. Here is the fixed snippet: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( ! -iname ".*" \) -print0 | while read -rd  $'\0' file ; do mv -- "$file" /other/location/ ; done`

Comment: @perer Just as a note that the `read -d` option is not portable to all shells, but if you are using `bash` anyways, `-d ''` should get you the same effect as `-d $'\0'`.

Comment: FWIW if you want this to run as a oneliner, add a `;` where each newline is now.

Answer (score 45):

It's easiest in zsh:

```
mv -- *([1,100]) /other/location/
```

This moves the first 100 non-hidden files (of any type, change `([1,100])` to `(.[1,100])` for *regular* files only, or `(^/[1,100])` for any type but *directory*) in name lexicographic order. You can select a different sort order with the `o` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers), e.g. to move the 100 oldest files:

```
mv -- *(Om[1,100]) /other/location/
```

With other shells, you can do it in a loop with an early exit.

```
i=0
for x in *; do
  if [ "$i" = 100 ]; then break; fi
  mv -- "$x" /other/location/
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

Another portable way would be to [build the list of files and remove all but the last 100](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56998).

Comment: +1 for safe shell expansion. Would also be more readable with the increment operation `$(( i++ ))` or `$[ i++ ]`?

Comment: @hesse Some shells don't implement `++` and `--`. You can write `: $((i+=1))` instead of `i=$((i+1))`; I'm not convinced that it's more readable.

Comment: :-D, I actually edited this answer thinking it was mine... Sorry. Feel free to revert as that changes the meaning.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I do wonder why you'd exclude directories and symlinks, the question said nothing about that.

Comment: @Gilles, the accepted answer has `ls -p | grep -v /` so has the recent question that dups here.

Comment: @Manuel I don't see why anything would be different on macOS. What's wrong?

Answer (score 11):

The following worked for me. Sorry if it was posted previously, but I did not see it in a quick scan.

```
ls path/to/dir/containing/files/* | head -100 | xargs -I{} cp {} /Path/to/new/dir
```

Comment: This was my first thought when I needed to do something similar, but I didn't know how to specify the stdin parameter to `xargs`, so your answer taught me something.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 9):

If you're not using zsh:

```
set -- *
[ "$#" -le 100 ] || shift "$(($# - 100))"
mv -- "$@" /target/dir/
```

Would move the last (in alphabetical order) 100 ones.

Brief explanation:

- The asterisk expands to all non-hidden files in the current directory (in alphabetical order) and `set` assigns them to the positional parameters: `$1`, `$2`, ... etc
- `$#` is the number of parameters, so we test if that is <= 100 and if so, we're done, otherwise we shift (i.e., remove) all but 100 parameters from the parameter list by computing `$# - 100`
- The remaining 100 (or fewer) parameters are stored in `$@` and are moved to `/target/dir/`

Answer (score 5):

To move a hundred of them at random:

```
shuf -n 100 -e * | xargs -i mv {} path-to-new-folder
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033129/how-to-move-a-given-number-of-random-files-on-unix-linux-os

That assumes none of the file names contain quotes or backslashes or start with blanks or `-` though. And since `mv`'s stdin is now a pipe, the prompts it may issue for user confirmation will not work. A more correct, reliable and efficient approach, with shells with support for ksh-style process substitution would be:

```
xargs -r0a <(shuf -zn100 -e -- *) mv -t path-to-new-folder --
```

Answer (score 3):

The following oneliner in shell would help.

```
 foreach i (`find Source_Directory -type f --max-depth 1|tail -100`); do; {mv $i Target_Directory}; done
```

Comment: What's that shell?

Comment: @phk, that would happen to work in `zsh` even if at first sight that looks quite alien to `zsh` syntax. Gilles has shown a much simpler way to do it in `zsh`. Even then, that's still more reliable than the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

the following command works, if you are interested in using `ls`

```
$ ls -rtd source/* | head -n100 | xargs cp -t destination
```

How does this work ??

- `ls -rtd source/*` - command lists all the files with the relative path from oldest to newest
- `head -n100` - takes first 100 files
- `xargs cp -t destination` - moves these files into the destination folder

Note that it assumes GNU `cp` and that file names don't contain blanks, newlines, quotes or backslash characters.

A more foolproof alternative with recent versions of GNU utilities would be:

```
ls --zero -rtd -- source/* | head -zn100 | xargs -r0 cp -t destination --
```

(`--`s not necessary here as file paths start with `source/`, but would be if you changed `source/*` to `*.txt` or `*` for instance).

Comment: This is a good answer. OP was asking how to move, not copy. But I believe this answer should also work by replacing the `cp` command with the `mv` command. They both support the `-t` flag.

Answer (score 1):

[mmv](http://linux.about.com/od/lts_guide/a/gdelts28.htm) is an outstanding utility which will also allow you to do mass renaming of files.  (I had to `sudo apt-get install mmv` on my computer to install it.)  Simple usage example: suppose you have a directory of files with extension .JPG that you'd like to change to a lowercase .jpg.  The following command does the trick:

```
mmv \*.JPG \#1.jpg
```

The backslash is used to show a wildcard is coming up.  The */JPG matches anything with a JPG extension.  In the "to" portion of the command, the #1 uses the matching text from the first wildcard to rename the file.  Of course, you can put a different path before the #1 to also move the file.

Comment: It would be more beneficial if you provided how you would actually use the tool you suggest to accomplish the goal.

Comment: added a usage example

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
c=1; d=1; mkdir -p NEWDIR_${d}
for jpg_file in *.jpg
do
if [ $c -eq 100 ]
then
d=$(( d + 1 )); c=0; mkdir -p NEWDIR_${d}
fi
mv "$jpg_file" NEWDIR_${d}/
c=$(( c + 1 ))
done
```

try this code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be safe / handle filenames with spaces, newlines, quotes, backslashes etc. in them, you have to use null-terminated separators:

```
find "$srcdir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | head -z -n 100 | xargs -0 -r -- mv -t "$destdir" --
```

**EDIT2:** **NOTE:** if you don't have `head -z` ([for whatever reason](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/467066/306023)) you can replace the above `head -z -n 1000` with `tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | head -n 1000 | tr '\0\n' '\n\0'` (or [see other ways](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467073/306023))

`-maxdepth 1` will avoid looking for files in subdirectories of `$srcdir`, so the only ones listed are the files within `$srcdir`.
`-print0` will use `\0` instead of newline(`\n`) between each listed file - this helps handle files containing newlines and spaces with xargs.
`head -z` will count `\0` terminated (instead of newline(`\n`) terminated) lines as lines. `-n 100` will list only the first `100` files that `find` found.
If you want to see what command `xargs` will execute, add `-t` (or `--verbose`).
`xargs -0` "Input items are terminated by a null (`\0`) character instead of by whitespace, and the quotes and backslash are not special (every character is taken literally)"
`xargs -r` will not run `mv` if there are no files to be moved (ie. if `find` did not find any files).
`--` terminates processing of arguments as options to the program, more details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/306023)

Sample output (runs one `mv` command and can handle files with newlines in their name too):

```
$ find /tmp/t -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | head -z -n 100 | xargs -t -0 -r -- mv -t /tmp -- ; echo "exit codes: ${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
mv -t /tmp -- /tmp/t/file containing quotes"' then spaces /tmp/t/file containing quotes"' /tmp/t/file containing a slash n here\n /tmp/t/file containing a new line here
and continues /tmp/t/s /tmp/t/-x and -L 1. /tmp/t/of replace-str in the initi /tmp/t/-thisfile_starts_with_a_hyphen and has spaces and a -hyphen here /tmp/t/-thisfile_starts_with_a_hyphen and has spaces /tmp/t/-thisfile_starts_with_a_hyphen /tmp/t/another      with       spaces /tmp/t/one with spaces /tmp/t/c /tmp/t/a 
exit codes: 0 0 0

$ ls -1R /tmp/t
/tmp/t:
a
'another      with       spaces'
b
c
'file containing a new line here'$'\n''and continues'
'file containing a slash n here\n'
'file containing quotes"'\'''
'file containing quotes"'\'' then spaces'
'of replace-str in the initi'
'one with spaces'
s
'some dir'
-thisfile_starts_with_a_hyphen
'-thisfile_starts_with_a_hyphen and has spaces'
'-thisfile_starts_with_a_hyphen and has spaces and a -hyphen here'
'-x and -L 1.'

/tmp/t/b:
'file with spaces'

'/tmp/t/some dir':
'some file'
```

For `find`:

```
-maxdepth levels
       Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of direc‐
       tories below the starting-points.  -maxdepth 0
        means only apply the tests and actions to  the  starting-points
       themselves.
-type c
       File is of type c:

       b      block (buffered) special

       c      character (unbuffered) special

       d      directory

       p      named pipe (FIFO)

       f      regular file

       l      symbolic link; this is never true if the -L option or the
              -follow  option is in effect, unless the symbolic link is
              broken.  If you want to search for symbolic links when -L
              is in effect, use -xtype.

       s      socket

       D      door (Solaris)
-P     Never follow symbolic links.  This  is  the  default  behaviour.
       When find examines or prints information a file, and the file is
       a symbolic link, the information used shall be  taken  from  the
       properties of the symbolic link itself.
-L     Follow symbolic links.  When find examines or prints information
       about files, the information used shall be taken from the  prop‐
       erties  of  the file to which the link points, not from the link
       itself (unless it is a broken symbolic link or find is unable to
       examine  the file to which the link points).  Use of this option
       implies -noleaf.  If you later use the -P option,  -noleaf  will
       still  be  in  effect.   If -L is in effect and find discovers a
       symbolic link to a subdirectory during its search, the subdirec‐
       tory pointed to by the symbolic link will be searched.

       When the -L option is in effect, the -type predicate will always
       match against the type of the file that a symbolic  link  points
       to rather than the link itself (unless the symbolic link is bro‐
       ken).  Actions that can cause symbolic links  to  become  broken
       while  find  is executing (for example -delete) can give rise to
       confusing behaviour.  Using -L causes  the  -lname  and  -ilname
       predicates always to return false.
```

For `head`:

```
-n, --lines=[-]NUM
       print the first NUM lines instead of  the  first  10;  with  the
       leading '-', print all but the last NUM lines of each file
-z, --zero-terminated
       line delimiter is NUL, not newline
```

**EDIT:** Someone [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/29221/5) that they didn't have `head -z`, this is the version that I was using(in Fedora 25):

```
$ head --version
head (GNU coreutils) 8.25
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie and Jim Meyering.

$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/head
coreutils-8.25-17.fc25.x86_64
```

For `xargs`:

```
-0, --null
       Input  items  are  terminated  by a null character instead of by
       whitespace, and the quotes and backslash are not special  (every
       character is taken literally).  Disables the end of file string,
       which is treated like any other  argument.   Useful  when  input
       items  might  contain  white space, quote marks, or backslashes.
       The GNU find -print0 option produces  input  suitable  for  this
       mode.
-r, --no-run-if-empty
       If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run
       the command.  Normally, the command is run once even if there is
       no input.  This option is a GNU extension.
-P max-procs, --max-procs=max-procs
       Run  up  to max-procs processes at a time; the default is 1.  If
       max-procs is 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible  at
       a  time.   Use the -n option or the -L option with -P; otherwise
       chances are that only one exec will be  done.   While  xargs  is
       running,  you  can send its process a SIGUSR1 signal to increase
       the number of commands to run simultaneously, or  a  SIGUSR2  to
       decrease  the number.  You cannot increase it above an implemen‐
       tation-defined limit (which is shown with  --show-limits).   You
       cannot  decrease  it  below  1.  xargs never terminates its com‐
       mands; when asked to decrease, it merely waits for more than one
       existing command to terminate before starting another.

       Please  note  that  it is up to the called processes to properly
       manage parallel access to shared  resources.   For  example,  if
       more  than one of them tries to print to stdout, the ouptut will
       be produced in an indeterminate order (and very likely mixed up)
       unless  the  processes  collaborate in some way to prevent this.
       Using some kind of locking scheme is one  way  to  prevent  such
       problems.   In  general, using a locking scheme will help ensure
       correct output but reduce performance.  If  you  don't  want  to
       tolerate  the  performance  difference,  simply arrange for each
       process to produce a separate output file (or otherwise use sep‐
       arate resources).
-t, --verbose
       Print  the command line on the standard error output before exe‐
       cuting it.
```

For `cp`:

```
-t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
       copy all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
-v, --verbose
       explain what is being done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find /source/directory -type f -maxdepth 1 -print | tail -100 | xargs -J % mv % /other/location/
```

**Note**: If you are using GNU xargs, then replace -J with -I 'xargs' option.

Comment: This is incorrect, you're passing three arguments to `mv`, the last one of which (probably) isn't a directory. And it doesn't really answer the question - the asker wants to move a given number of files, not all of them.

Comment: Command updated.

Comment: Results in: xargs: invalid option -- 'J'

Comment: @navjotk It seems you have GNU xargs on your machine, please replace -J option with -I.

Answer (score 0):

I came by here, but I was needing to copy files in parts (99 each) from `/DIR1` to `/DIR2`. I'll paste the script here to help otherz maybe:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Thanks to <Jordan_U> @ #ubuntu
# 06 Dec 2014

i=0
copy_unit=98

for file in /DIR1/*; do
  cp "$file" /DIR2
  if [[ "$i" -ge "$copy_unit" ]]; then
    echo "Pausing, press enter to continue"
    read
    i=0
  fi
  ((i++))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With a Perl one-liner (using `\0 NULL byte` as file separator, handling files with newlines, spaces or starting with a dash, and quitting on error with explicit message):

```
count=100
perl -Mautodie -se '
    my @files = <*>;
    rename($_, "./other/dir/$_") for @{files[0..$count]}
' -- -count="$count"
```

Answer (score -1):

Another variation, inspired by https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105042/66736 :

```
cp `ls -d ./* | head -n 100` tmpi
```

It may not be the fastest or the most elegant way, but it is a way you can keep in memory.

Answer (score -2):

I know this thread is a pretty old, but I found the answers more complicated than I thought they should be.  This worked in CentOS, but it seems simple enough that it should probably work in other distros.

```
cp `ls someDir | head -n 100` someDir100/
```

Comment: That doesn't work because the output of `ls` won't include the leading `somedir/` prefix, and won't work for filename with blank or wildcard characters or start with `-`.

Comment: Fair enough.  I actually did
cp `ls | head -n 100` ../someDir100/
From inside the target directory and none of the file names satisfied those cases.  Better to be lucky then good!