# Copy first n files in a different directory

Tags: cp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to move 100 files from a folder containing thousands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12976/how-to-move-100-files-from-a-folder-containing-thousands)

Is it possible to copy only the first 1000 files from a directory to another?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "first"? Did you look at [this related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12976/how-to-move-100-files-from-a-folder-containing-thousands) ?

Comment: If a folder has 50000 files copy only the first 1000. I'll look at the question thnx.

Comment: What to you mean by "first"? Alphabetical? By time changed/accessed? Any set of 1000?

Comment: Any without criteria

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to copy files using batches.

Comment: Yes that's what I am trying to do.

Comment: Since I can't answer: this solution seems like the cleanest of them all: `cp \`ls | head -500\` ./subfolder1/`. You might want to be in the directory to copy from such that `ls` can work properly. Also, it assumes none of the filenames contain space, tab, newline, star, open square bracket, question mark characters or start with - or . and assuming subfolder1 itself does not show up in that list (credits to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105040/how-to-move-the-first-x-files).

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The following copies the first 1000 files found in the current directory to `$destdir`. Though the actual files depend on the output returned by `find`.

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f |head -1000|xargs cp -t "$destdir"
```

You'll need the GNU implementation of `cp` for `-t`, a GNU-compatible `find` for `-maxdepth`. Also note  that it assumes that file paths don't contain blanks, newline, quotes or backslashes (or invalid characters or are longer than 255 bytes with some `xargs` implementations).

**EDIT:** To handle file names with spaces, newlines, quotes etc, you may want to use null-terminated lines (assuming a version of `head` that has the `-z` option):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | head -z -n 1000 | xargs -0 -r -- cp -t "$destdir" --
```

Comment: @chchrist, Mark this as answer.

Comment: doesn't work to me if paths has spaces in it

Comment: @onur [`I couldn't find any version of head that has a '-z' option. Otherwise thanks for the improvement`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/29221/5)  Then the above edit doesn't work as intended(ie. there's no 1000 files limit anymore, it's all files), if head isn't treating lines as null terminated! `head -z` exists for me on Fedora 25: `$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/head` result `coreutils-8.25-17.fc25.x86_64` package.  Also see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467153/306023) answer where I used `head -z`.
I'm curious, what distribution did you check for `head -z` availability? Thanks.

Comment: There is a workaround for those not having `head -z` see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467073/306023 So the above becomes then: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | head -n 1000 | tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | xargs -0 -r -- echo -t "$destdir" --`  ie. replace `head -z -n 1000` with `tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | head -n 1000 | tr '\0\n' '\n\0'`

Comment: `head -z` gives `invalid option` error in Debian jessie/sid version.

Comment: @onurgüngör Marcus is right though, if you've got `find` printing everything on one line with `-print0`, `head` isn't going to work, so I don't think your last example is right. Want to incorporate the workaround posted in that comment instead?

Comment: @onurgüngör I think you need to update your version. The `man` page [listed for sid](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/coreutils/head.1.en.html) does include the `-z`.

Answer (score 4):

A pure shell solution (which calls `cp` several times).

```
N=1000;
for i in "${srcdir}"/*; do
  [ "$((N--))" = 0 ] && break
  cp -t "${dstdir}" -- "$i"
done
```

This copies a maximum number of `$N` files from `$srcdir` to `$dstdir`. Files starting with a dot are omitted. (And as far as I know there's no guaranty that the set of chosen files would even be deterministic.)

Answer (score 0):

The following scary 1-liner:

```
perl -MFile::Copy -e 'opendir(DIR,$ARGV[0]);$n=1000; (-f $_) && copy($_,"$ARGV[1]/$_") while($n-- && readdir(DIR))
```

works for file containing spaces, quotes, etc., which tend to break shell-based solutions (short of $IFS contortions). 'Course if your file names are behaved, shell is fine.

Edit: added check for copying only files.