# keep N files in subdirectories

Tags: command-line, files, rm

I'm trying to do something that looks pretty simple but I haven't been able to solve.

I have a directory with a bunch of subdirectories all of them with multiple files (jpg files). I want to execute a command which keep only 4 or N files inside of these directories. The order of the files isn't important as I have seen related questions depending on the time they were created

I have played with ls + head and trying to put find in a loop with the -delete option but still no luck.

Comment: Schoolwork? If not - then please clarify what you need and why. Just keeping 4 random files seems strange. If the order is not important - then all answers using date would be usable. Or something like this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29214/copy-first-n-files-in-a-different-directory
It will furthermore add credibility if you actually showed what you have attempted.

Comment: why I need to add an explanation or purpose if that's not needed to understand the question? Anyway, just for you, I have a bunch of folders full of images which I got from a scraper but I only need to keep 4 of them for my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
for dir in /target/dir/*/; do
  (cd -- "$dir" && set -- *.jpg && [ "$#" -gt 4 ] && shift 4 && rm -f -- "$@")
done
```

Which with `zsh`, you could shorten to:

```
for dir (/target/dir/*(/)) rm -f $dir/*.jpg(N[5,-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those are regular files with no blanks, newlines, quotes, backslashes or invalid characters in their paths:

```
find /target/dir/ -type f \
  | awk '{t=$0; gsub(/\/[^/]*$/, "", t); if(a[t]++ < 4) print}' \
  | xargs rm --
```

See the comments below for how you could possibly adapt it for more funny file names if your utilities support certain extensions.

Comment: `xargs` takes a blank or newline separated list on input when quotes and backslashes can be used to escape those separators and each other.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yeah, forgot about `xargs`.

Comment: Yes, `xargs` is pretty much useless without GNU's `-r0` extensions (and then you'd need GNU `awk -v 'RS=\0' -v 'ORS=\0'`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Shouldn't `-d '\n'` be suffice in the real world?

Comment: That's better but that still doesn't solve the problem with newline characters. It's also a lot less portable than `-0`