# How can I execute an equivalent of `head -z` when I don't have the `-z` option available?

Tags: coreutils, head, coreos

I need `head -z` for a script (off-topic, but the motivation can be found [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1072087/538283)), but in my CoreOS 835.13.0 I get `head: invalid option -- 'z'`.

Full `head --help` output:

```
Usage: head [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Print the first 10 lines of each FILE to standard output.
With more than one FILE, precede each with a header giving the file name.
With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -c, --bytes=[-]K         print the first K bytes of each file;
                             with the leading '-', print all but the last
                             K bytes of each file
  -n, --lines=[-]K         print the first K lines instead of the first 10;
                             with the leading '-', print all but the last
                             K lines of each file
  -q, --quiet, --silent    never print headers giving file names
  -v, --verbose            always print headers giving file names
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

K may have a multiplier suffix:
b 512, kB 1000, K 1024, MB 1000*1000, M 1024*1024,
GB 1000*1000*1000, G 1024*1024*1024, and so on for T, P, E, Z, Y.

GNU coreutils online help: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Report head translation bugs to <http://translationproject.org/team/>
For complete documentation, run: info coreutils 'head invocation'
```

The funny part is that the last line tells me to run `info coreutils 'head invocation'` but I get `info: command not found`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap NULs and NLs before and after head:

```
<file tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | head | tr '\n\0' '\0\n'
```

With recent versions of GNU `sed`:

```
sed -z 10q
```

With GNU `awk`:

```
gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '{print}; NR == 10 {exit}'
```