# z flag for head command in centos 7

Tags: centos, find, head

I was reading this answer by @dessert: https://askubuntu.com/a/990771/853133 about how to delete old backup folders from directory using cron in Ubuntu. The command given was:

`find /BACKUPDIR/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | sort -z | head -zn-6 | xargs -0 echo rm -rf`

However, CentOs 7 doesn't like the z flag in his call to head:

`head: invalid option -- 'z'`

Is there a work-around for CentOs7?

I took a look at: [How can I execute an equivalent of `head -z` when I don't have the `-z` option available?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467066/how-can-i-execute-an-equivalent-of-head-z-when-i-dont-have-the-z-option-a) I don't think this explanation is applicable to my question. I don't see how I would change my command if I want to delete backups older than n.

Comment: Is it important that you specifically keep the last _six_ backups, or do you just want to remove backups older than a certain threshold?  If age is the key, you could just use `find [...] -delete`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti: My preference is just the last n backups...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, support for NUL-delimited records has being added gradually to GNU utilities over the past few decades. GNU `head -z` is relatively recent (2015), while GNU `sort` has had `-z` for decades (1996) and `xargs` `-0` even longer (1990).

Here, you could also do:

```
find /BACKUPDIR/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 |
  sort -rz | sed -z 1,6d | xargs -r0 echo rm -rf
```

The `-z` addition to GNU `sed` is recent (2012), not as recent as `head`'s.

GNU text utilities have been able to cope with NUL bytes in their input for decades, so you can always do:

```
find /BACKUPDIR/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 |
  tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
  sort -r | tail -n +7 | 
  tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
  xargs -r0 echo rm -rf
```

Or you can always install `zsh` and do

```
echo rm -rf /BACKUPDIR/*(D/[1,-7])
```

(see also it's `n` glob qualifier to sort numerically so 10 sorts after 9 instead of between 1 and 2).

(dates above are from ChangeLogs, the official releases where those changes were included may have come a little later).