# How to split the subdirectories of a directory in n parts?

Tags: bash

I have a directory with 52 subdirectories, and I'd like to split them in 11 folders with 5 subdirectories each of them.
Can anyone suggest me a way to achieve this?

Comment: You could use a python script.

Comment: This may be useful as well.. just make sure your new $file names are not at the end of ls when tail is run: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12976/how-to-move-100-files-from-a-folder-containing-thousands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first place, you're asking for a mathematical impossibility, but I'll overlook it.

The basic thing you ask is very simply done:

```
[ ! -e split ]       &&
set ./*/             &&
while  mkdir split   &&  [ 4 -lt "$#" ]
do     mv "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" split
       mv split "${1%/}"
       shift 5
done&& mv "$@" split && mv split "${1%/}"
```

Because you don't specify any kind of names or similar that takes some care to avoid overwriting anything, and winds up just moving every 5 directories as sorted lexicographically into a directory named for every 5th. That is, it does so if there is no file or directory in the current directory named *split*

Comment: That works pretty well, though I wonder if it is possible to put a sequential name like folder01, or something similar?

Comment: @RodrigoMoralesAlvarado -- of course it is possible, but you didn't ask for it, and you didn't provide any list of names. it would have been irresponsible of me to suggest you do so if there had been a *folder01* in the directory already.

Comment: Yeah, well there is any folder with that name, neither split.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i get it wrong but you could try something like this:

```
ls -1 | awk '{tmp=int($NR/5);system("mkdir Folder"$tmp);system("mv "$1" Folder"$tmp)}'
```

Comment: This works well, except in the case that there is files in the main folder, because it also creates a folder for it and copy it.  Is there anyway to exclude files?

Comment: Yeah only use ls -1d */ instead

Comment: When I'm run a test with 6 directories, it move each directory to a new one with the prefix Folder, but do not split them in 5 folders for each new folder.