# AMD microcode not updating

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, hardware, gentoo, amd

I have recently installed Gentoo Linux on my AMD Ryzen 7 1700X.
Now I face [segmentation faults during heavy compilation loads](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Ryzen#Segmentation_faults_during_compilation) and also [random restarts in an idle state](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Ryzen#Random_reboots_with_mce_events).

As a very first step I verified the current microcode version:

```
grep -m 1 microcode /proc/cpuinfo
microcode       : 0x8001126
```

However, according to [this table](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Ryzen#Ryzen_7) the latest microcode should be 0x08001129.
It thus seems to be a good idea to update the microcode for the CPU.

So I emerged `=sys-kernel/linux-firmware-20180730` (containing `/lib/firmware/amd-ucode/microcode_amd_fam17h.bin`).
Further, I enabled the following options in the kernel:

```
CONFIG_MICROCODE=y
CONFIG_MICROCODE_AMD=y
```

After a reboot, I tried loading the microcode manually (late microcode update):

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/microcode/reload
```

However, when I do this, no new line appears in `dmesg`:

```
dmesg | grep microcode
[    0.465121] microcode: CPU0: patch_level=0x08001126
[    0.465514] microcode: CPU1: patch_level=0x08001126
[    0.465932] microcode: CPU2: patch_level=0x08001126
[    0.466394] microcode: CPU3: patch_level=0x08001126
[    0.466772] microcode: CPU4: patch_level=0x08001126
[    0.467159] microcode: CPU5: patch_level=0x08001126
[    0.467537] microcode: CPU6: patch_level=0x08001126
[    0.467908] microcode: CPU7: patch_level=0x08001126
[    0.468268] microcode: CPU8: patch_level=0x08001126
[    0.468653] microcode: CPU9: patch_level=0x08001126
[    0.468999] microcode: CPU10: patch_level=0x08001126
[    0.469409] microcode: CPU11: patch_level=0x08001126
[    0.469744] microcode: CPU12: patch_level=0x08001126
[    0.470136] microcode: CPU13: patch_level=0x08001126
[    0.470455] microcode: CPU14: patch_level=0x08001126
[    0.470757] microcode: CPU15: patch_level=0x08001126
[    0.471092] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
```

I would expect something like `microcode: CPU0: new patch_level=0x08001129`.
What am I missing here?
Some kernel `CONFIG_` option?
Can I turn on some sort of debug information?
Or even better – how can I list the microcode version provided in `microcode_amd_fam17h.bin`?

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
CONFIG_PREVENT_FIRMWARE_BUILD=y
CONFIG_FIRMWARE_MEMMAP=y
CONFIG_MICROCODE=y
# CONFIG_MICROCODE_INTEL is not set
CONFIG_MICROCODE_AMD=y
CONFIG_MICROCODE_OLD_INTERFACE=y
CONFIG_FW_LOADER=y
CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE="amd-ucode/microcode_amd_fam17h.bin"
CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE_DIR="/lib/firmware"
# CONFIG_FW_LOADER_USER_HELPER is not set
```

(Note, if you want to list more than one file in `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE` they should be space separated, and their paths should be relative to `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE_DIR`.)

But that is possibly not going to work (it works for me if using graphics and network firmware only, haven't tried with CPU firmware), so, try another way: ignore the value for `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE` above(ie. don't set it; but maybe the other ones are still needed, unsure) and instead try [early microcode loading](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/microcode.txt) by prepending the CPU microcode file to the initramfs file, maybe something like this(in Gentoo):

`/etc/kernel/postinst.d/25-glue_cpu_microcode_to_kernel`:

```
#!/bin/bash

bootdir='/bewt'
initramfsfname="initramfs"
initramfs="$( realpath -- "/${bootdir}/${initramfsfname}" )"
vmlinuz="/${bootdir}/kernel"

prepend_microcode () {
  echo "prepending CPU microcode to ${initramfs}"
  local destfirst="/tmp/initrd/"
  local destmc="${destfirst}/kernel/x86/microcode/"
#  mkdir -p "${destmc}"
    install -dm644 "${destmc}"

  #this will replace the symlink /bewt/initramfs (on gentoo) with the file!
  #but this makes genkernel fail as such: 
  #ln: failed to create symbolic link 'initramfs.old' -> '': No such file or directory
  #even though it doesn't touch the .old file!
  # so to fix this, we'll use realpath above!

  ( cp -f "/lib/firmware/amd-ucode/microcode_amd.bin" "${destmc}/AuthenticAMD.bin" && cd "${destfirst}" && find . | cpio -o -H newc > "../ucode.cpio" 2>/dev/null && cd .. && cat "ucode.cpio" "${initramfs}" > "/tmp/${initramfsfname}" && chmod a-rwx "/tmp/${initramfsfname}" && mv -f "/tmp/${initramfsfname}" "${initramfs}" )
    local ec=$?
    if [[ $ec -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "success."
    else
        #TODO: make errors be red so it's more obvious
        echo "failed!"
    fi
    return $ec
}

prepend_microcode
```

However `genkernel` might (still? 3 years later) ignore files in `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/` (or that was only happening in 2015 and got fixed since, or maybe for some other reasons), which means you'll have to manually run `genkernel` yourself(to compile kernel) and then, after it, manually run all in scripts [present](https://github.com/ActualizeInMaterial/manjarred/tree/master/system/Z575/OSes/gentoo/on_baremetal/filesystem_now/gentoo/etc/kernel/postinst.d) in `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/`, doing so looks like [this](https://github.com/ActualizeInMaterial/manjarred/commit/ce9320104b7528bf0b79789238256b455480456c#diff-e0a8bd174cdd61818182dfbe91017ee0R43):

`` echo "!! Running genkernel..."
time genkernel all --bootdir="/bewt" --install --symlink --no-splash --no-mountboot --makeopts="-j4 V=0" --no-keymap --lvm  --no-mdadm --no-dmraid --no-zfs --no-multipath --no-iscsi --disklabel --luks --no-gpg --no-netboot --no-unionfs  --no-firmware --no-integrated-initramfs --compress-initramfs --compress-initrd --compress-initramfs-type=best --loglevel=5 --color --no-mrproper --no-clean --no-postclear --oldconfig
ec="$?"
if test "$ec" -ne "0"; then
  echo "!! genkernel failed $ec"
  exit "$ec"
fi
echo "!! Done genkernel"
list=( `find /etc/kernel/postinst.d -type f -executable | sort  --general-numeric-sort` )
echo "!! Found executables: ${list[@]}"
for i in ${list[@]}; do
  ec="-1"
  while test "0" -ne "$ec"; do
    echo "!! Executing: '$i'"
    time $i
    ec="$?"
    echo "!! Exit code: $ec"
    if test "$ec" -ne "0"; then
      echo "!! something went wrong, fix it then press Enter to retry executing '$i' or press C-c now."
      #exit $ec
      time read -p -s "!! Press Enter to re-execute that  or C-c to cancel"
    fi
  done
done ``

(note: the bootdir used above is `/bewt` instead of `/boot`, so you might want to change at least that; also the string `microcode_amd.bin` above should be replaced with yours: `microcode_amd_fam17h.bin`)
That `list=` and `for` above is not [the proper way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467153/306023) to handle file names, unless they have no spaces, newlines etc. which is obviously assumed above.

If you want to take a look at an old 4.1.7 kernel `.config` that did cpu-firmware early loading, see [this one](https://github.com/ActualizeInMaterial/manjarred/blob/ce9320104b7528bf0b79789238256b455480456c/system/Z575/OSes/gentoo/on_baremetal/filesystem_now/gentoo/etc/kernels/kernel-config-x86_64-4.1.7-hardened-r1-g45b4b78#L1093).

Comment: The kernel configuration exactly matches my setting. The early microcode loading also doesn't work. The last thing I didn't try is initrd. I will try it tomorrow... (perhaps?) However, I don't think this is the problem. Currently, I consider adding some debug printk directly to `/usr/src/linux/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/microcode`...

Comment: @DaBler If I were to guess, and I might be wrong here, I'd say that this particular [`if`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.8/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/microcode/amd.c#L357) block isn't entered; the reason seems to be that it's because the microcode revision in the CPU is already at least as high as the one on the disk. However I'm aware that this shouldn't be the case for you, according to all the info in OP. So maybe it's this other [`if`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.8/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/microcode/amd.c#L182) that enters instead! What motherboard do you have?

Comment: Ignore my `What motherboard do you have?` question. I thought that [`CFG Lock`](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/40925413/45669263-cd724b00-bb1f-11e8-9169-f7585150cb9e.jpg) in my BIOS had anything to do with updating microcode, but looking into [it](https://github.com/coreboot/coreboot/blob/c703beb31d8f95c1e861cb4007b02c3eaaf93c33/src/soc/intel/common/block/include/intelblocks/msr.h#L35), it doesn't seem to; it's about C States and power management.

Comment: Please let me know what you find by adding those debug printk, I'm really curious if this [`if`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.8/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/microcode/amd.c#L182) block gets hit. I really think there should be a message when the microcode update fails and it should state current and on-disk microcode revision numbers. (for inspiration see [this](https://github.com/xftroxgpx/a3/blob/b6ccab4d7134cd1a018d2c2cd202519379f5e6fa/system/Z575/OSes/3archlinux/on_baremetal/filesystem_now/archlinux/home/xftroxgpx/build/1packages/kernel/linuxgit/boris4of2.patch) and boris3of2.patch)

Comment: If you want you could try running [spectre-meltdown-checker](https://github.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker), for it says (to me on Intel)   `* CPU microcode is the latest known available version:  YES  (latest known version is 0x96 according to Intel Microcode Guidance, August 8 2018)`. Maybe you'll get a similar message(?)

Comment: Even the microcode stored in an initrd file did not help. I'll try to add some `pr_info`s as you suggested.

Comment: The  spectre-meltdown-checker says: `CPU microcode is the latest known available version:  UNKNOWN  (latest microcode version for your CPU model is unknown)`

Comment: I have just added a lot of `pr_info` calls to `arch/x86/kernel/cpu/microcode/…` The call path for early builtin microcode loading goes through `apply_microcode_early_amd`, `scan_containers` to `parse_container`, but never hits [this block](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.65/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/microcode/amd.c#L149)… which may be the problem. Not sure anyway. The call path for `find_microcode_in_initrd` goes the same way. In the case of late loading, the path ends with the `Not reloading previously-loaded already-in-effect microcode!` (in the patch you linked).

Comment: I am not sure what to do now. It would be fine to list the content of the microcode file.

Comment: I've no idea how `to list the content of the microcode file`. On another note: assuming you already have SMT disabled, do you have this [commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=07d981ad4cf1e78361c6db1c28ee5ba105f96cc1) in your kernel ? What about this (non-SMT related) [one](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=8da38ebaad23fe1b0c4a205438676f6356607cfc) ?

Comment: I have the first commit in my kernel (`=sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.14.65`). I however don't have the second one. (I can try it later.) I have added a lot of debug printings and [this](https://textuploader.com/dvnkq) is what I currently see in `dmesg|grep microcode`. The `/proc/cpuinfo` still reports patch level `0x8001126`.

Comment: Looks like you should get patch `0x08001227` :D but due to `cache_find_patch return NULL` you don't, my guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83492/discussion-between-marcus-linsner-and-dabler).

Comment: [Updated dmesg output](https://textuploader.com/dvnl5) It seems that the container contains patch for rev id `0x8012` whereas my cpu rev id is `0x8011`.