# How much disk space do the files in a list use?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

How can I find how much disk space the files in a list use? I'm looking for a variation of

```
du -s *.sql
```

I want to see only the grand total, and the command above always shows a line for each file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `du -c` to get the grand total then pipe through `tail` to get only the last line (the total):

```
du -c -- *.sql | tail -n 1
```

There seems to be no way to make `du` itself report *just* the total of a set of files.

The `--` is not required but highly recommended if this command is to be used in a script. It marks end of options and protects against some funny filenames. See here for more info [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean)

---

Some technical nitpicks:

If any `*.sql` files are "hidden" (filename start with a dot) then they will not be included. This is because by default the glob does not include hidden files.

For `*.sql` that are directories `du` will include *all* files in those directories recursively.

Using zsh you can write `*.sql(^/)` to exclude directories. Or `*.sql(D)` to include hidden files. For more info look up zsh glob qualifiers.

For `*.sql` that are symlinks `du` will count the size of the link itself instead of the target it points to. Use `du -H` to get the size of the target of the link.

Beware that in any case most `du` implementations including GNU `du` will only count the disk usage of unique files. So if `foo.sql` is a hard link to `bar.sql` (or a symlink and `-H` is used) its disk usage will only be counted once.

This might cause confusion if you plan to copy the files to a filesystem that does not support hardlinks. In most cases the hardlinked files will be copied twice and you will end up needing more disk space on the target system than shown by `du`.

With the GNU implementation of `du` the `-l` option can be used to skip the deduplication.

Answer (score 4):

What doesn't work from your example?  Do you want a sum? 
`man du` shows that the `-c` option provides a sum of usage:

```
du -sc -- *.sql
```

You may also like the `-h` or `-k` arguments.

Comment: See my clarification. I want it to print only the sum.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very ambiguous but I suspect you are looking for the `-c` flag to produce a total.

```
du -c -- *.sql
```

Comment: I want it to have the same effect as `du -s dir`. Which will summarize disk usage of the directory, and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Though not standard, with some `du` implementations, you can add a `-h` option to get *human readable* disk usage that use `K`/`M`/`G`/`T`... suffixes for kibibyte/mebibyte/gibibyte/tebibyte...

```
du -sch -- * | tail -n 1
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the accepted answer of `du -c * | tail -n 1`.  Also the `-s` option doesn't do anything here.

Comment: This is essentially a combination of the other answers.  The `-h` option is not called for; the OP didn't ask for it.  `| tail -n 1` is better than `| grep total` because there might be files whose names contain the word `total`.

Comment: @Wildcard: Actually, `-s` decreases the amount of data being written through the pipe (if any of the argument(s) are directories).

Comment: Aha!  @G-Man, good catch; you're right.

Comment: that's why i added -s flag ... my understanding of original query is that is wanted the grand total of all files from subdirectories combined in separate grand totals not the listing for every file each how much space eat. If not then -s is wrong will eat all files from subdirectories. Tail -n 1 is ever better, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can generate a list of files (or whatever) using find you can also:

```
find {directory} {matching expression} -exec stat -c "%s" {} \; | awk 'BEGIN{total=0} {total=total+$1} END{print total/1000000.00}'
```

For example to see the total size (in MB) of all .jar files in /some/dir:

```
find /some/dir -name '*.jar' -exec ...
```

While this does exec a process for each file the result is fairly quick.

Comment: (1) This would be a good case for using `-exec … +`. (2) The user might not appreciate output like “4.2e-05” or “17123.5”.  [Look at `numfmt`.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106330/80216#699628 "Sort all directories based on their size")

Comment: `%s` is for size, not disk usage. That implies the GNU implementation of `stat`, but if you have GNU `stat`, you'll likely have GNU `find` which can report that information by itself (with its `-printf` which existed decades before GNU coreutils added a `stat` command).

Answer (score -4):

```
cat *.sql | wc -c
```

Answer is in bytes.

Comment: Yeah, but you need to read the whole whopping 10Gb in order to tell it...