# Sort all directories based on their size

Tags: ksh, disk-usage, sort

I'd like to sort all the directories/files in a specific directory based on their size (using *du -sh "name"*).

I need to apply this command to all directories in my location, then sort them based on this result.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Related: [Converting a variable to human readable format (KB, MB, GB)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31569739/3960947).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

With GNU sort and GNU du (which it appears you have, since you state you are using `du`'s `-h` option):

```
du -sh -- *  | sort -rh  # Files and directories, or
du -sh -- */ | sort -rh  # Directories only
```

The output looks something like this:

```
22G     foo/
21G     bar/
5.4G    baz/
2.1G    qux/
1021M   wibble/
4.0K    wobble/
```

Comment: Note that if a file is hard linked in two or more directories, then the sizes of each directory reported by `du` depends on the order of the directories on the command line.  Also, `-h` is available on other `du` implementations than GNU.

Answer (score 5):

Sort by sizes (as unformatted numbers of kibibytes)
and then turn those into human readable:

```
du -sk -- * | sort -nr | cut -f2 | xargs du -sh
```

Comment: This fails if the directory names contain whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

This is an improved version based on jabalv's answer. It works with a GNU as well as a BSD userland.

```
IFS='\n' du -sk -- * | sort -n | cut -f2 |
while read line ; do
  xargs du -sh "$line"
done
```

sample output:

```
4.0K  games
2.7M  local
6.7M  lib32
19M   sbin
152M  src
177M  include
321M  bin
2.2G  share
2.9G  lib
```

To reverse the sort order and list the largest files and directories first, use `sort -nr`.

Comment: (1) How is this “an improved version”? It still fails if the directory names contain whitespace. (2) Does  `IFS='\n'` do anything useful? (3) Does setting `IFS` *at the point in your answer where you have set it* have any effect on the execution?

Answer (score 0):

This improves on [jabalv's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106330/80216#106337), fixing the space in names issue:

```
du -sk -- * | sort -nr | awk -F '\t' '{print "\""$2"\""}' | xargs du -sh
```

Comment: OK, this fixes the problem for ***spaces*** in directory names.  It still fails for other whitespace.  I’ll admit that it is very hard to write complex commands that handle filenames that contain *newlines* correctly, but this also fails for names that contain *tabs.* … or *quote characters* (`"`).  Also, before I fixed it, it could have failed for filenames beginning with **`-`** (hyphen/dash). … … … … … … … … … … … … … P.S. Please don’t refer to “the above answer”, as different people see the answers in different orders.

Answer (score 0):

As inspired by [jabalv’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106330/80216#106337),
sort by sizes (as unformatted numbers of kibibytes)
and then turn those into human readable numbers
— without running `du` a second time:

```
du -s -- * | sort -n | numfmt --from-unit=1024 --to=iec
```

or

```
du -s --block-size=1 -- * | sort -n | numfmt --to=iec
```

- You can add the `-k` option to the first command line (i.e., `du -sk`)
  to specify that output should be in kibibytes,
  but this seems to be the default.
- Use `*/` instead of `*` to list directories only,
  as in [Chris Down’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106330/80216#106332).
- Add the `-r` option to the sort command (i.e., `sort -nr`)
  if you want to sort from high to low.
- Use `--from-unit=1024` because `du` uses [binary prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) notation
  (i.e., K=1024, M=2<sup>20</sup>, etc.) by default.
- Likewise, use `--to=iec` to output binary-prefix numbers.
- This replaces the tabs in `du`’s output with spaces. 
  Add `--padding=-7` to the `numfmt` command
  to get the output to look like it has tabs. 
  (I guess it is counting zero-based.) 
  (`--padding=7` (without the **`-`**) would right-justify the numbers.)

Answer (score -2):

This command should work:

`sudo du -sh $(sudo ls) | sort -h`

Comment: Can you explain the need for each `sudo` and why you're using `ls`?  Note that this would break for anything containing spaces.

Comment: @Kusalananda there is no need for each `sudo`. I wrote that because sometimes I was denied access to run this command. I use ls to list all the directories and use them as input to the `du` command. But yes, you are absolutely correct, this would definitely break for directories with whitespaces.