# How do I change the extension of multiple files?

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename

I would like to change a file extension from `*.txt` to `*.text`. I tried using the [`basename`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/basename.1.html) command, but I'm having trouble changing more than one file.

Here's my code:

```
files=`ls -1 *.txt`

for x in $files
do
    mv $x "`basename $files .txt`.text"
done
```

I'm getting this error:

> basename: too many arguments Try basename --help' for more information

Comment: Some ideas at http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/shellscripting/batch_rename too

Comment: You can use find: `find . -iname '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'mv -- "$1" "${1%.txt}.text"' bash {} \;`

Comment: This script is ok, but you put $files (the full list) as parameter of basename instead of $x (the current file); the line should be `mv $x "\`basename $x .txt\`.text"`.

Comment: In a simple case, I've used awk:

>  ls -1 *.txt | awk -F "." '$0 " " $1 ".text"' | xargs -n 2 mv

Answer (score 542, accepted):

Straight from [Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030):

```sh
# Rename all *.txt to *.text
for file in *.txt; do
    mv -- "$file" "${file%.txt}.text"
done
```

`*.txt` is [a globbing pattern](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob), using `*` as a wildcard to match any string. `*.txt` matches all filenames ending with '.txt'.

`--` [marks the end of the option list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash). This avoids issues with filenames starting with hyphens.

`${file%.txt}` is [a parameter expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9559024/1709587), replaced by the value of the `file` variable with `.txt` removed from the end.

Also see the entry on why you [shouldn't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

If you have to use `basename`, your syntax would be:

```sh
for file in *.txt; do
    mv -- "$file" "$(basename -- "$file" .txt).text"
done
```

Comment: One liner ```for f in *.txt; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.txt}.text"; done```

Comment: For those who found this answer, be warned that if you *mistakenly* replace curly braces by parentheses in the "parameter expansion" syntax, it would remove your file. Don't make the same mistake as I did (luckily i used a test dir).

Comment: Sharing my experience on using this answer.  I used directly these lines in my shell script to rename the file. I just replaced for f in *.txt with my file path.
cd /u1/test/myfiles
for f in /u1/test/myfiles
mv -- "$f" "$(basename -- "$f" .txt).text"
done

Above line worked well and rename the files correctly, but there is a catch. It won’t rename and copy at
/u1/test/myfiles same location. It will copy at last location of your shell script. The path which we can see using pwd command. We just need to cd on path first.

Comment: One more tip - for quick little scripts like this, I often prepend `echo` in front of the command in the `do` statement ... this has the result of outputting just what the script is about to do, without actually doing it.

Answer (score 239):

Here's how I change all the file extensions in the current directory on **Debian or Ubuntu**.

```
rename "s/oldExtension$/newExtension/" *.txt
```

(This is the Perl `rename` command, not the `util-linux` one. See [Why is the rename utility on Debian/Ubuntu different than the one on other distributions, like CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275254/170373))

On MacOS, user [Monkpit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/112592/monkpit) reports that they were able to use `brew install rename` to get this to work.

Comment: with fish shell you can do `rename "s/oldExtension/newExtension/" **.txt` to rename all *.txt recursively

Comment: When your files don't have any extension and you want to add one: `rename 's/$/.txt/' *`

Comment: This would be ideal, rather than the chosen best answer. Anyway, note that different linux distros have different implementations of ```rename```; e.g. OpenSuse uses ```util-linux.rename``` and won't work with regular-expressions (meh.. ), so not ideal for file-extension renaming.

Comment: I tried **➜  Comp ✗ rename "s/oldExtension$/jsx/" *.js**
but get **zsh: no matches found: *.js** edit, how do we make this recursive ?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper, in `zsh`, use `zmv`: `autoload zmv; zmv '(**/)(*.js)' '$1${2}x'`

Answer (score 84):

A simple command, [`rename` from `util-linux`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html), will do that for you. It replaces every occurrence of "txt" with "text" in all files matching "*.txt":

```
rename txt text *.txt
```

Comment: `rename` changes the first occurrence, so better make that `rename .txt .text`, but this still won't always work (e.g. it renames `foo.txtx.bar.txt` to `foo.textx.bar.txt`).

Comment: It should be noted that not all systems have the same version of rename; on Debian and friends, the `rename` command is actually `perl-rename` and uses perl regexes. For that, the equivalent command would be: `rename 's/.txt/.text/' *.txt`. People should check the `man rename` on their system to find out which one they have.

Comment: @evilsoup That's the case for OSX, thx

Comment: This also works on Cygwin (Windows)

Comment: Replace rename with rename.ul on Ubuntu/Debian.

Comment: There is no `rename` in the [util-linux](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/util-linux/filelist) package on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 67):

```
rename "s/oldExtension/newExtension/" *.txt
```

Above works fine but is limited to the current directory. Try the command below, which is flexible with sub-directories. It will rename all `.txt` files under the directory structure with a new extension.

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec rename 's/\.txt$/.newext/' '{}' \;
```

Comment: `rename` can handle multiple files as argument, you can vastly speed things up by using `+` instead of `\;` if there are many such files

Comment: Still, it is a useful option since "*.txt" can unroll to a large argument list unsupported by the shell.

Comment: "s/oldExtension/newExtension/" will fail for `footxt.txt`. Use this instead: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19654/changing-extension-to-multiple-files/383321#383321

Answer (score 42):

The answers here referencing `s/oldExtension/newExtension/` are wrong. If you use `s/txt/text/`, you would convert `footxt.txt` to `footext.txt`, which is not what you want. Even if you use `s/.txt/.text/`, that would convert `footxt.txt` to `fo.text.txt`.

You have to use `\.` to match the period (`.` will match any character). And the trailing `$` to match the end of the line. Only this will properly match the extension.

```
rename 's/\.txt$/.text/' *.txt

rename 's/\.old$/.new/' *.old
```

Answer (score 33):

Reason #53 to switch to zsh:

`zmv '(*).txt' '$1.text'`

Comment: For Mac, I have to run this command "autoload -U zmv". Otherwise, I am getting "zsh: command not found: zmv"

Comment: I'm guessing `autoload -U zmv` means, on "my user profile" autoload zmv. Thanks a bunch for this =)

Comment: Running `zsh 5.8 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)`. No `zmv` command. is it supposed to be installed by default?

Comment: @Olsgaard 1) It's not a command actually, it's a ZSH [**_function_**](https://opensource.apple.com/source/zsh/zsh-30/zsh/Functions/Misc/zmv.auto.html). 2) As was mentioned above, you need to execute `autoload` in order to use `zmv` (read this: ["What does autoload do in zsh?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840651/what-does-autoload-do-in-zsh)). Also here is a nice tutorial: ["How to use `zmv` — Z Shell’s super-smart file renamer"](https://blog.smittytone.net/2021/04/03/how-to-use-zmv-z-shell-super-smart-file-renamer/).

Answer (score 15):

```
for f in *.txt
do
    [ -f "$f" ] && mv "$f" "${f%txt}text"
done
```

Answer (score 15):

Based on the @Prince John Wesley answer, here is a simple bash script for changing all extensions of files in the current directory from `ext1` to `ext2`. Also outputs names of the files being renamed.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.$1
do
    [ -f "$f" ] && mv -v "$f" "${f%$1}$2"
done
```

Example usage (assuming the name of the script is `change-ext`):

```
change-ext ext1 ext2
```

Comment: To change extensions of files in directories recursively, replace the second line (`for...`) with two lines: `shopt -s globstar` and `for f in **/*.$1`. Requires Bash 4+.

Answer (score 13):

let's say your files are scattered in various directory,
Assuming that dirx is your parent directory, this can do the job using find:

```
for f in `find /dirx -iname '*.txt' -type f -print`;do  mv "$f" ${f%.txt}.text; done
```

Comment: What about tcsh..

Comment: I used the following for changing all old Arduino files with .pde to .ino in RadioHead examples sub folders: for f in find /examples -iname '*.pde' -type f -print;do mv "$f" ${f%.pde}.ino; done – 
BobC
 just now   Edit   Delete

Answer (score 11):

On Ubuntu 18.04, the [util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) rename command is available as `rename.ul`. This worked for me:

```
rename.ul -o -v .oldext .newext *.oldext
```

Options:

- -o: don't overwrite preexisting .newext
- -v: verbose
- -n: dry run

For more info, see [`man rename.ul`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/util-linux/rename.ul.1.en.html) or `rename.ul -h`.

Answer (score 7):

When you

> do not have an extension for the source files

and target extension is **.text** you would do it this way -

```
for f in *; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.\*}.text"; done
```

Comment: Excellent bash-native script. worked great! `for f in *.html; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.\*}.pug"; done`

Comment: This does not change the extension. It adds to it. You have to use basename to extract the base part of the filename.

Answer (score 6):

This is what works for me:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec rename 's/\.txt$/.text/' \{} \;
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to know what went wrong in your version: You used `$files` instead of `$x` in the basename command. So this should work (untested, though):

```
for x in *.txt
do
  mv "$x" "`basename "$x" .txt`.text"
done
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me! 

Comment: as a oneliner renaming `.mta -> .sta`. Does not fail, if no .mta files are present: ```for f in `ls *.mta 2> /dev/null`; do mv "$f" "`basename "$f" .mta`.sta"; done```

Answer (score 5):

Mmv (available in the main distributions repositories) is also very useful for renaming. Give the patterns **in quotes** and each glob element can be reproduced by `#N`:

```
mmv '*.txt' '#1.text'
```

Some more interesting, neat examples in the [manual page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/mmv/mmv.1.en.html):

> Rename files ending in `.html.en`, `.html.de`, etc. to ending in `.en.html`, `.de.html`, etc.:
>
> ```
> mmv '*.html.??' '#1.#2#3.html'
> ```
>
> Rename music files from `<track no.> - <interpreter> - <song title>.ogg` to `<interpreter> - <track no.> - <song title>.ogg`:
>
> ```
> mmv '* - * - *.ogg' '#2 - #1 - #3.ogg'
> ```

Answer (score 3):

A very simple solution, based on the old good **xargs**, to add a suffix/extension to filenames corresponding to <pattern>:

```
ls <pattern> | xargs -i mv {} {}.<suffix>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nobody has shown using shell parameter expansion, which is the most basic, probably shell compliant, (and I believe most readable) way of doing this.

```
# by removing suffix 
for f in *.txt; do echo "$f" "${f%txt}text"; done

# by substitution
for f in *.txt; do echo "$f" "${f/%txt/text}"; done

# simply edit mv for echo after testing
# % searched for shortest string, %% is 'greedy' would search for longest
# if you have a basename, use basename*.txt
```

https://www.debuntu.org/how-to-bash-parameter-expansion-and-string-manipulation/ 
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in *.old_ext; do
  mv -- "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed "s/\.old_ext$/.new_ext/")"
done
```

I am posting this because I have not seen another answer that details this method and why it could potentially be superior to the accepted answer. [You can go here to see all the reasons why this method is better than all the other answers](https://github.com/phx/phxutils/tree/master/chext), but basically, the accepted answer is not POSIX-compliant since it relies on `bash` parameter expansion.

I realize OP tagged `bash` specifically, and for that reason, the accepted answer will work just fine, but if you wanted to use this command in a shell script on a system using `sh` or `dash`, you could use the version I posted above, which utilizes any version of `sed` (GNU/BSD/anything), and will work just fine, while not relying specifically on `bash` itself.

I actually wrote that command for this specific use case, which I encounter frequently and have been using it as a `bash`/`zsh` function for a long time, which I named `chext`:

```
chext() {
  old_ext="$1"
  new_ext="$2"
  for file in *.${old_ext}; do
    mv -v -- "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed "s/\.${old_ext}$/.${new_ext}/")"
  done
}
```

**Usage:**

`chext [old_extension] [new_extension]`

Recently, I had the need to use it on a different computer, and instead of just a one-off copy/paste, I actually added it to my main set of portable commands, [phxutils](https://github.com/phx/phxutils).

After publishing `chext` in `phxutils`, I did a quick search to see if there was actually a better way of accomplishing what I set out to do, and after browsing through all of these answers, I still think my way is the best and most universal (at least for current directory extension replacement -- for other methods, I would use one of the `find` variations)

Answer (score 0):

For a slightly different take, in the case of a directory under git version control, you might consider:

```
# Rename all *.txt to *.text
for file in *.txt; do 
    git mv -- "$file" "${file%.txt}.text"
done
```

In my case this avoided having git think the files were simply deleted.