# How can I rename all files in the current directory having a particular extension to another extension?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, filesystems, directory, rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Renaming multiple files (changing extension)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19654/renaming-multiple-files-changing-extension)

Suppose that in my current/working directory I have five files:

```
file1.xvg
file2.xvg
file3.xvg
file1.eps
file2.eps
```

Is there any way that I can rename all files in the current/working directory with the extension **.xvg** and give them the new extension **.txt** (leaving the **.eps** files alone)?  Can this be done with `rename`, `mv`, or `mmv` perhaps?  I am using Ubuntu Linux.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your particular question this command will work. Verify that you are happy with the proposed renaming, then drop the `-n` to have the operation proceed.

```
rename -n 's/\.xvg$/.txt/' *.xvg
```

This basically means for all files with the `.xvg` extension in the current directory find the files that end (`$`) with `.xvg` and change that part of the name to `.txt`.

More detail and an example below.

---

Yes, the `rename` command will do this for you. A short example where I rename all of my files with the `.html` extension to `.html_bak`, ignoring other files in the directory.

I would ***strongly*** recommend using the `-n` command line option *first* (explained below) to see what changes would happen before executing the actual command.

What I start out with:

```
$ ls
a.html  a.txt  b.html  htmlfile
```

the `-n` means do a "trial run" .. just show what would change, don't change anything!

```
$ rename -n 's/\.html$/.html_bak/' *
a.html renamed as a.html_bak
b.html renamed as b.html_bak
```

Still have the original files.

```
$ ls
a.html  a.txt  b.html  htmlfile
```

Now for real:

```
$ rename  's/\.html$/.html_bak/' *
```

Files have been renamed.

```
$ ls
a.html_bak  a.txt  b.html_bak  htmlfile
```

In the above examples I use `*` to specify the files to be considered for the rename operation. I could have restricted this to `.html` files only with `*.html`.

For more information consult the rename man page

Answer (score 3):

This can be done like this:

`rename 's/xvg$/txt/' *.xvg`

The glob pattern ensures that only `*.xvg` files are affected.