# Why is the rename utility on Debian/Ubuntu different than the one on other distributions, like CentOS?

Tags: debian, centos, rename, utilities, distributions

On CentOS, the rename command uses two simple strings, `from` and `to`.

```
rename from to file...
```

while on Debian/Ubuntu it uses a perl-style regular expression.

```
rename [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] perlexpr [ files ]
```

Why does this utility differ based on the distribution? Is there a reference for which distributions ship or default to which versions of the utility?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/117549

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but here is how to [use each of the two syntaxes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238862/135943).

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks! Very useful, though I'd still like to know more about why each family of distros uses which version of the utility.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

History. There are two historical lines of a `rename` command, with the same basic purpose but completely different syntax and capabilities:

- The `rename` command in the [util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) package. It appeared in version 2.10e and the program is dated 2000-01-01.
- A perl script, which was distributed with [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) as an example program. The Debian changelog records it being added to Debian in June 1999 (the program itself dates back to at least 1992). Another version, which is backward compatible, comes with [Unicode::Tussle](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::Tussle) (as of Debian jessie, it's called `file-rename`, and provided in the [`rename` package](http://packages.debian.org/jessie/rename); some other distributions call it `prename`).

On the one hand, util-linux is a core package, so it's more standard than the Perl example script which was included at Debian's whim. On the other hand, the Perl script was in Debian first. So far, Debian has chosen to preserve compatibility with past Debian release, rather than align with other distributions. Distributions derived from Debian (Ubuntu, Mint, elementary, etc.) tend to follow Debian on this point.

Other distributions didn't have a `rename` command when one was added to util-linux, so they naturally include the util-linux version.

Comment: `/usr/bin/rename` is not part of any package. At least `dpkg -S /usr/bin/rename` does not return anything.

Comment: @FaheemMitha It's a [symlink to `/etc/alternatives/rename`](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives), which defaults to the Perl version (but can point to the util-linux version instead, at the choice of the administrator).

Comment: @FaheemMitha That's because /usr/bin/rename is controlled by debian's alternatives system.   try `update-alternatives --display rename`.  debian allows the local sysadmin to choose between util-linux or perl rename (or others, if any exist)

Comment: hmmm, that's odd.  on my `sid` system, `util-linux` doesn't provide an alternative for `/usr/bin/rename`.  but another package `rename` does, so the choices are `/usr/bin/prename` from `perl`  (priority 60) or `/usr/bin/file-rename` from `rename` (priority 70).   `file-rename` seems to be an updated/enhanced version of `prename`.

Comment: @cas `file-rename` is the Unicode::Tussle version. I think the reason `rename.ul` isn't an alternative for `rename` is because it's incompatible; but an administrator who favors consistency between distributions can still manually change the link to point to `/usr/bin/rename.ul`. I don't know if this would break any Debian scripts; in principle, according to policy, packages can count on the perl version if they depend on `perl`, and build scripts can count on the perl version since the `perl` package is build-essential.

Comment: @Gilles that's pretty much what i thought.