# How can remove suffix including hyphen and number in Linux filename?

Tags: linux

I have some text file like this

```
access-2018-08-21.log.1-20180906
access-2018-08-22.log.1-20180906
```

I want to remove the -20180906 part wo the result would be

```
access-2018-08-21.log
access-2018-08-22.log
```

I tried `rename -- "s/\-20180906//g" *` but it didn't work.

What's the command line i need to achieve my goal?

Comment: Wrong `rename` utility? See [Why is the rename utility on Debian/Ubuntu different than the one on other distributions, like CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275254/170373) and check what `rename --version` says.

Comment: Does not work in what way? Also, your command is a bit wrong. Something like the following suffices: `rename "s/\.1-20180906//g" *`

Comment: Hi, it didn't work in a way that doesn't remove the -20180906 part. And by the way, your above-mentioned command also doesn't remove the -20180906 part.

Comment: Sorry, I re-edited the comment. But what is the precise output when it doesn't work?

Comment: @GAD3R Your command also doesn't work. :(

Comment: @Sparhawk It didn't have any output. After executing your command, i used ls to check and the file name still remained.

Comment: Thanks. And as per the other comment, what is the output of `rename --version`?

Comment: Here's the output 
rename from util-linux 2.30.2

Comment: Okay, thanks. So @ikkachu's link is spot on. Have a read of that. You need the perl version of rename instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

if you are happy with the output, then just remove the echo word.

```
for i in access*; do echo mv $i ${i%.*}; done
```

Comment: Just started using the `{...}` expansions in some of my scripts. It's much faster than spawning a new process with `$(...)`

Comment: @Kamaraj   s/cp/mv/