# Rename a specific part of a lot of files

Tags: rename

I have a bunch of files named:

```
Brooklyn Nine-Nine S01 E01 [H264].mkv
Brooklyn Nine-Nine S01 E02 [H264].mkv
Brooklyn Nine-Nine S01 E03 [H264].mkv
Brooklyn Nine-Nine S01 E04 [H264].mkv
Brooklyn Nine-Nine S01 E05 [H264].mkv
Brooklyn Nine-Nine S01 E06 [H264].mkv
Brooklyn Nine-Nine S01 E07 [H264].mkv
Brooklyn Nine-Nine S01 E08 [H264].mkv
...
```

I want to rename them so that the space Between S01 and E08 is removed.
example

```
Brooklyn Nine-Nine S01E08 [H264].mkv
```

I already found a command to remove all spaces:

```
IFS="\n"
for file in *.mkv;
do
    mv "$file" "${file/[[:space:]]}"
done
```

but I only want to remove space between Sxx and Exx.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the `rename` tool, which lets you do a simple search-and-replace in many filenames:

`rename [options] <expression> <replacement> <file>...`

Something like this should do:

`rename " E0" E0 Brooklyn*.mkv`

Note that if you're using a Debian-like distribution, your `rename` command probably calls a Perl script with a different input syntax instead of the usual utility from `util-linux`. In that case, use `rename.ul` to call the right tool. [Why is the rename utility on Debian/Ubuntu different than the one on other distributions, like CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275254/251216)

Answer (score 0):

The for loop can be edited as follows:

```
for file in *.mkv;
do
   mv "$file" "${file//S01 E0/S01E0}"
done
```

or using the `rename` command:

```
rename 's/S01 E0/S01E0/' *.mkv
```