# Remove all characters after file extension

Tags: regular-expression, rename, mv

I've got dozens of files such as:

```
title.mkv]-[72+167] - "" yEnc  637005001 (1+889)
```

I'd like to remove everything after "**.mkv**"

I tried looking up some regex that would help me, but I don't understand how to use them.

Could somebody help me?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note on `rename`, `prename` etc. see:

- [Why is the rename utility on Debian/Ubuntu different than the one on other distributions, like CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275254/140633)
- [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/140633)

In this answer the Perl variant is used, not the one form util-linux. As in not:

```
$ rename --version
rename from util-linux 2.31.1
```

but:

```
$ rename --version
/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 0.20
```

or similar.

---

With Perl rename:

```
rename 's/\.mkv.*/.mkv/s' ./*.mkv*
```

Use the `-n` option first to make sure it does what you want.

```
rename -n 's/\.mkv.*/.mkv/s' ./*.mkv*
```

In short:

```
s/\.mkv.*/.mkv/s
```

is:

```
substitute/<THIS>/<WITH THIS>/s
```

`\.mkv.*` matches a literal dot `\.` then the string `mkv` and finally any character (including `\n` for which you need the `s` flag) zero or more times `.*`.

Result is replace `.mkv<anything>` with `.mkv`.

---

There is tools to help with reading and building expressions, like https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. It was actually a solution I found earlier as well, but wasn't able to make it work. Turns out I was using the rename package that didn't use Perl... oops.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack: Yeah. Thought of mentioning it, but did not at first (bad of me), updated with more detail for others.

Answer (score 1):

With [`zsh`'s `zmv`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv):

```
autoload zmv
zmv -v '(*.mkv)*' '$1'
```

Removes the part after the *rightmost* occurrence of `.mkv` in the filename (renames `foo.mkv-bar.mkv-whatever` to `foo.mkv-bar.mkv`).

For the *leftmost* occurrence (to rename that file to `foo.mkv` instead), you could replace `*.mkv` with `*.mkv~*.mkv?*` which matches a string ending in `.mkv` but which also otherwise does not contain `.mkv` followed by at least one character using the `~` "except" [glob operator](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators).

Answer (score 1):

in `bash`:

```
for f in *; do [[ "$f" =~ ^.+\.mkv ]] && mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

In a script
bash

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.mkv*
do
  j=$(echo "$i" | sed -e 's/\.mkv.*$/.mkv/')
  mv -- "$i" "$j"
done
```