# Rename Multiple Files using xargs without using a loop

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a folder with files

```
a1.cpp
a2.cpp
a3.cpp
a4.cpp
a5.cpp
a6.cpp
```

I wish to change extension of files ending in the range 2 to 5 to .java

How do I rename those files without using a loop and with the help of xargs?

the final output would be

```
a1.cpp
a2.java
a3.java
a4.java
a5.java
a6.cpp
```

Comment: Why do you have to use xargs?  Is it a homework question?

Comment: Not really. I am learning efficient ways to use xargs. 
I am a software developer with 4 years of experience :)

Comment: Are you aware that this could be done with a single `rename` command exploiting shell expansions?

Comment: @FelixJN no I am not. would you please help me with it

Comment: I think AdminBee covered that in his answer by now.

Answer (score 5):

As always when using `xargs` with filenames, you [must be careful](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice?noredirect=1&lq=1) if your filenames contain non-trivial characters.

That said, and assuming you have the GNU version of `find` and `xargs` with the `-print0` and `-0` options, the following will do:

```
find . -type f -name 'a[2-5].cpp' -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/cpp$/java/'
```

This will use `find` to generate the list of relevant files according to your requirement, and output them as NULL-terminated string to ensure that filenames with spaces etc. are correctly handled. Then, `xargs` with the corresponding `-0` option is used to invoke the (external) `rename` tool to which you can supply a `sed` style name transformation command (note that this assumes the Perl-based `rename` tool, not the util-linux variant, as noted by @ilkkachu - see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275254/170373) for a discussion).

I don't know if that can be called an "efficient way" to use `xargs`, but from your comment I take it that you want to explore `xarg`s possibilities, and this is a reasonably reliable way to do it. The task you describe can be done entirely without `xargs` using exactly that `rename` command by using shell syntax features, as in:

```
rename 's/cpp$/java/' a[2-5].cpp
```

If you don't have the Perl version of `rename`, but the `util-linux` variant, the corresponding command would be

```
rename ".cpp" ".java" a[2-5].cpp
```

However, for lack of RegEx-Style anchors this will replace the *first* occurence of the original pattern with the substitution. In this case, where the task is to change the file suffix, this is unlikely to be a problem because `.cpp` will only occur once, at the end of the name, but in the general case you have to be careful when formulating the command.

Comment: Thank @AdminBee. It worked

Comment: @SamMend You're welcome. I added it to the answer. If you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.

Comment: @AdminBee Another `find`/`xargs` hint: If you're going to `xargs` something risky (`mv`, `rm`, `apt uninstall`, ... ) stick an `echo` in front of your command and look at the command you're generating.

Comment: +1.  Also, perl `rename` can take a list of filenames on stdin (with `\n` as the default separator, or NUL with `-0`), so `xargs` is redundant.    `find ... -print0 | rename -0 's/cpp$/java/'`