# mv No such file or directory? renaming files in multiple directories

Tags: shell-script, rename, mv

This is partly because I have a very shallow understanding of BASH.

Here is the script:

```
eighteen=(2018*/*)
newe=`echo "$eighteen" | sed -e 's/\(-\)*$//g'`

while read f <&3 && read nf <&4; do     
    mv -v "${f}" "${nf}"
    break
done 3<"$eighteen" 4<"$newe"
```

I am trying to compensate the lousy script I wrote, and delete `-` symbol at the end of each filename in multiple subfolders.

and the error I get: `./cleanup.sh: line 16: 2018-08-13/untitled-102.arw: No such file or directory`

It is worth to note, that the error comes not from `mv` line, but from this: `done 3<"$eighteen" 4<"$newe"`.

I copied the while loop from the answer on StackExchange. Quick food, usually, is not good for digestion, and quick solutions - for understanding, please help me to understand. Give me a hint on how previously mentioned substitution `4<"$newe"` `nf <&4` is called, how should I search to learn more about it. Is it applied outside `while` statement context?

Comment: A `while` loop doesn't look right here. This Q&A might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19654/how-do-i-change-the-extension-of-multiple-files The error you are seeing looks to be due to `<"$var"` which perhaps should have been `<<<"$var"`.

Comment: @guest Thanks a lot, that is just what I was looking for. Turns out, there was no need for such a complicated solution I was thinking of. Will learn more at [Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030).

Comment: I think [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) about backticks could be useful for you.

Comment: You declare an array of `glob`, then call the variable as `$eighteen`, but it's not a simple variable

Comment: And you don't have to struggle with `IO redirections` (>&4...) for this simple tasks. Copying without understanding is randomly useful

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. Please see [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @GillesQuenot thanks for the advice. I have not tried your answer, and therefore won't flag it as the one that solved my problem.                                                               Greg's wiki and @ guest's comment helped me a lot though.

Comment: @guest See question answer's comment above. You may want to write a proper answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seems to use a plain buggy shell script where you can just use the proper tool, keeping your regex:

```
rename -n 's/-*$//' 2018*/*
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good to rename for real.

[man rename](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/rename/file-rename.1p.en.html)

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

The rename command that is part of the `util-linux` package, won't.

If you run the following command:

```
$ rename
```

and you see `perlexpr`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo apt install rename
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /usr/bin/file-rename
```

---

For archlinux:

```
pacman -S perl-rename
```

---

For RedHat-family distros:

```
yum install prename
```

The 'prename' package is in the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository.

---

For Gentoo:

```
emerge dev-perl/rename
```

---

For *BSD:

```
pkg install gprename
```

or `p5-File-Rename`

---

For Mac users:

```
brew install rename
```

---

If you don't have this command with another distro, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>