# Renaming all files in a certain directory and sub directory on MacOS?

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename, macos

I'm trying out the code that answers this questions:

[How do I change the extension of multiple files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19654/how-do-i-change-the-extension-of-multiple-files)

I tried this:

```
# Rename all *.js to *.ts
for f in *.js; do 
    mv -- "$f" "${f%.js}.ts"
done
```

However that results in this:

```
Oles-MacBook-Pro:src oleersoy$ ./rename.sh 
mv: rename *.js to *.ts: No such file or directory
```

I also tried this:

```
rename js ts *.js
```

And the result of that is:

```
Bareword "js" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 2) line 1.
```

Thoughts?

Comment: You don't have any files matching the pattern `*.js` in the current directory.

Comment: Ah ... Do you know if there's a way to make it do the current directory and sub directories?

Answer (score 0):

OK - found this on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985492/recursively-change-file-extensions-in-bash

And this works:

```
find . -name "*.t1" -exec rename 's/\.t1$/.t2/' '{}' +
```