# How to use sed on symbolic linked files?

Tags: linux, sed, rename, symlink

I have some symbolic linked files and some normal files like below:

```
P_2_UC34_31_1.gz
P_2_UC34_31_2.gz
P_2_UC34_32_1.gz
P_2_UC34_32_2.gz
P_2_UC34_33_1.gz
P_2_UC34_33_2.gz
```

`P_2_UC34_31_1.gz` and `P_2_UC34_31_2.gz` are symbolic links. The other 4 files are normal files (not symbolic links).

I'm trying to add `_Ms` before the `_1` and `_2` in all the files.

For the symbolic links I tried like below:

```
sed -i --follow-symlinks 's/_1/_Ms&/g' *.gz
```

But this didn't work. I didn't get any error and the file names are not changed.

I want the output to be like below:

```
P_2_UC34_31_Ms_1.gz
P_2_UC34_31_Ms_2.gz
P_2_UC34_32_Ms_1.gz
P_2_UC34_32_Ms_2.gz
P_2_UC34_33_Ms_1.gz
P_2_UC34_33_Ms_2.gz
```

Comment: `sed` operates on the contents of files, not their names. You probably just ruined those gzip files irrecoverably (unless you have backups, which I hope you do). What you want is a tool for renaming, like `perl-rename` (or whatever it is called in your OS)

Comment: okay, Is there a way I can add `_Ms` to all those files before `_1` and `_2`?

Comment: Yes, as I said, get the Perl rename command. What it's called varies with distributions (see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/70524) Then you can do `prename 's/_[12]\./_Ms&/g' *.gz` (or `perl-rename` or `rename` or whatever it maybe). So you restored the files from backup?

Comment: I tried this way but didn't work `rename 's/_[12]\./_Ms&/g' *.gz`

Comment: Ah, it should be `$&`, not `&`. `perl-rename 's/_[12]\./_Ms$&/g' *.gz` works for me. You might want to double check whether your `rename` is actually the Perl one or the util-linux one or something else altogether.

Comment: Okay I used this way and it worked. `for file in *_1.gz; do mv "$file" "${file%_1.fq.gz}_Ms_1.fq.gz"; done` no need of any `rename` of `perl-rename`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the extension of multiple files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19654/how-do-i-change-the-extension-of-multiple-files)

Comment: Now that you've answered your own question, please either post the answer and mark it as such, for the benefit of others who have similar issues, or remove the question to keep the question space clean.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment by the author of the question:

Okay I used this way and it worked.

```
for file in *_1.gz; do
     mv "$file" "${file%_1.fq.gz}_Ms_1.fq.gz";
 done
```

No need of any `rename` or `perl-rename`.

---

If the script has to change something, it needs a small correction, e.g.

```
for file in *_1.fq.gz; do
     mv "$file" "${file%_1.fq.gz}_Ms_1.fq.gz";
 done
```

For the solution of the original question this would be something like

```
for x in 1 2; do
  for file in *_${x}.gz; do
     mv "$file" "${file%_${x}.gz}_Ms_${x}.gz";
  done
done
```

(The complicated inner expression deserves a test: `file="aaaa_1.gz"; x=1; echo  mv "$file" "${file%_${x}.gz}_Ms_${x}.gz"; echo output is mv aaaa_1.gz aaaa_Ms_1.gz`.)

---

I add:

The problem is not related to `sed` (which does not rename files, only changes a text) nor to symbolic links (which get well renamed by the script).

The finest thing in the script is `%` in `"${file%_1.fq.gz}_Ms.....`.
There, `${file}` would expand to the content of variable `file` but `%_1.fq.gz` indicates that the string `_1.fq.gz` should be removed at the end, if posible.

The part `_Ms.....` is simply added to the string.

Comment: The thing is that even though the OP provided this answer in the comments, the substitution they used will not work on the set of example files

Comment: @roaima I added some corrections. Does that work now ?

Comment: Indeed :-) But you could also test, with something like `mkdir /tmp/t; cd /tmp/t; touch touch P_2_UC34_3{1_1,1_2,2_1,2_2,3_1.gz,3_2}.gz` and then apply the code