# Dashes in printf

Tags: bash, printf

I'm trying to use printf to format some pretty output in a bash script

e.g.:

```
-----------------------  
| This is some output | 
-----------------------
```

But I've stumbled over some behavior I don't understand.

```
$ printf "--"
```

gives me the error:

> printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]

and

```
$ printf "-stuff"
```

results in

> -bash: printf: -s: invalid option

So apparently printf thinks I'm trying to pass some arguments while I'm not.

Meanwhile, completely by accident, I've found this workaround:

```bsh
$ printf -- "--- this works now ----\n"
```

gives me

```
--- this works now ----
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean

Comment: Out of intereset, are there any implementations of `echo` that would fail when doing `echo ------------`? Most only support `-n` (no trailing newline), `-e` (interpret backslash-escaped chars) and possible `-E` (do NOT interpret them) and do not error out when other option-like arguments are encountered, right? (EDIT: GNU's `/bin/echo` also supports `--help` and `--version`.)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The `--` is used to tell the program that whatever follows should **not** be interpreted as a command line *option* to `printf`.

Thus the `printf "--"` you tried basically ended up as *"`printf` with no arguments"* and therefore failed.

Comment: In other words, to print `--` you can run `printf -- --`.

Comment: ... and `printf --` is the same as `printf` (you get the same message)

Comment: Note that `printf -- $fmt` is not portable.  On busybox 1.30.1, `printf -- '%s\n' hello` yields `--`.  See also: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html

Comment: @kelvin, What?  [busybox/printf.c#L421](https://github.com/brgl/busybox/blame/abbf17abccbf832365d9acf1c280369ba7d5f8b2/coreutils/printf.c#L421)

Comment: @AlexanderShukaev My bad, I tested it on LineageOS and now I see that it uses `mksh` in `adb shell` instead of busybox. It works normally with `busybox printf -- '%s\n' hello`. The point about portability still stands though.

Comment: @kelvin - Why would `printf -- '%s\n' hello` yields `--`? It is not shown in that man page.

Comment: @midnite "Why would `printf -- '%s\n' hello` yields `--`? It is not shown in that man page." I had tested that command on `adb shell` and that was the output. If you want to know why exactly that happens, you'd probably have to read the source code of the mksh version used by `adb shell`.

Comment: @kelvin - I see. Thanks for reply. So this seems to be a special behaviour of mksh. It does not happen to most of the other shells, e.g. bash.

Comment: @kelvin - Just check in from my LineageOS, which `adb shell echo "$SHELL"` shows `/system/bin/sh`. It seems that its `printf` is treating its `$1` as formatting string ALWAYS. `adb shell printf aa bb cc` gives `aa`. `adb shell printf -v bb cc` gives `-v`. `adb shell printf %s bb cc` gives `bbcc`. `adb shell printf %c bb cc` gives `bc`. Note that I by purpose miss out the quotation marks.

Comment: @midnite "Just check in from my LineageOS, which `adb shell echo "$SHELL"` shows `/system/bin/sh`. It seems that its `printf` is treating its `$1` as formatting string ALWAYS." Interesting; when I read your first comment I had already forgotten the reason for this behavior, but indeed always treating `$1` as the format (just like printf(3p)) seems to be it. Thanks for the details. By the way, the same behavior happens on the built-in "Terminal Emulator" on LineageOS, which appears to use the same shell (see the output of `sh -v`).

Answer (score 45):

`--` is being interpreted as an option (in this case, to signify that there are no more options).

A format string should *always* be included when using `printf` to prevent bad interpretation. For your particular case:

```
printf '%s\n' '-----------------------'
```

Comment: what about when you need to do this with a sequence? `printf '-%.0s' {1..54}`

Comment: @qodeninja Then you actually *do* want to use `--` :-) `printf -- '-%.0s' {1..54}`

Comment: @qodeninja `printf '\055%.s' {1..54}`

Comment: how portable is this?

Comment: @CervEd This is POSIX, it's highly portable. Certainly more so than `printf --`, which doesn't work in (for example) mksh.

Comment: @ChrisDown I meant `printf --` :(

Answer (score 12):

There are differences between printf builtin and /usr/bin/printf, the second one do "what you mean" without these annoying errors.

```
printf "-----"             # error
printf -- "-----"          # ok
/usr/bin/printf "-----"    # ok
/usr/bin/printf -- "-----" # ok
```

Comment: FYI `/usr/bin/printf '--'` gives **/usr/bin/printf: missing operand** error.

Answer (score 3):

POSIX provides the option of using octal encoding.

```
 printf "--"
```

can become:

```
printf "\055-"
```

This is a portable way to avoid the ambiguity of whether `--` is being used as a format string or as a marker for the end of options.