# Command "paste - - - - ", how to specify a big column number

Tags: command-line, text-processing, fedora, command, programming

In command `paste - - - -`, numbers of `-` is equal the future column number. In my case, I have 55,000 future column, for me wont need to put 55,000 `-` what I will can use?

Example:

```
title1:A1
title2:A2
title3:A3
title4:A4
title5:A5

title1:B1
title2:B2
title3:B3
title4:B4
title5:B5

title1:C1
title2:C2
title3:C3
title4:C4
title5:C5

title1:D1
title2:D2
title3:D3
title4:D4
title5:D5
```

I want to transform this file (A) into following:

```
title1 A1   title1 B1   title1 C1   title1 D1   title2 A2
title2 B2   title2 C2   title2 D2   title3 A3   title3 B3
title3 C3   title3 D3   title4 A4   title4 B4   title4 C4
title4 D4   title5 A5   title5 B5   title5 C5   title5 D5
```

For this, I used :

```
$ sed 's/:/ /; /^$/d' sample.txt \
    | sort | paste - - - - -
```

But in my file, I will have a big column number: 55,000 or 400 column. 
What is the other form to replace the `-` ??

Comment: Is that output what you really wanted?  A mix of different titles across the line (eg line 1 has 4 "title1" and 1 "title2".

Comment: @sthephenharris I'm sorry, In output I want only the "title1" in line 1, only "title 2" in line 2, etc. Because after I want that beeing : 
(Line1) title1       a1      b1      c1       d1
(Line2) title2       a2      b2      c2       d2

Do you understand what I wanted?

Comment: try `paste $(for i in {1..400}; do echo -n '- '; done)` or whatever number you want.. got idea from http://stackoverflow.com/a/5349772/4082052

Comment: or `paste $(printf -- "- %.s" {1..400})`

Comment: @spasic thank you. Worked out! I tried the first: paste $(for i in {1..400}; do echo -n '- '; done)

Comment: Clarification needed:  Is the output a diagonal transpose, (i.e. the current output column#1 has {A1,B2,C2...}), or was that a typo for a regular transpose, (in which case  column #1 would be {A1,A2,A3...})?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String multiplication trick based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349772/4082052

---

Use substitution to insert programmable number of dashes

```
paste $(for i in {1..400}; do echo -n '- '; done)
```

or

```
paste $(printf -- "- %.s" {1..400})
```

To know why `printf --` was used: [Dashes in printf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22764/dashes-in-printf)

Answer (score 0):

For a file with 4 rows:

```
 paste $(for((i=1;i<4;i++)); do echo -n "- "; done; echo -n "-") < file
```