# Strange behavior in $(dirname `readlink -f $0`)

Tags: bash

When I run the following as a normal user, everything is fine:

```
$(dirname `readlink -f $0`)
```

But after I switched to root, the following error occurred:

```
readlink: invalid option -- 'b'
Try `readlink --help' for more information.
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
```

Any ideas? I tried on local Fedora 16 and Amazon EC2, both running bash shell.

Apologize that I did not further illustrate the issue here. Here is the scenario:

Using normal user account:

```
$ pwd 
/home/myuser 
$ export MY_DIR=$(dirname `readlink -f $0`) 
$ echo MY_DIR 
/home/myuser
```

Using root user account:

```
# pwd
/root
# export ROOT_DIR=$(dirname `readlink -f $0`)
readlink: invalid option -- 'b'
Try `readlink --help' for more information.
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.

# export ROOT_DIR=echo $(dirname `readlink -f -- $0`)
# echo $ROOT_DIR
/root
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should be the same error as in a user login shell, because in a login shell the `0` shell parameter, expanding to the name of the current process, gives `-bash`, the minus indicating the login shell. You now see where the `-b` error comes from.

Try instead

```
echo "$( dirname "$(readlink -f -- "$0")" )"
```

Comment: What does the `--` ("minus minus" or "dash dash") indicate? Nevermind - I found the answer here: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376)

Answer (score 4):

If you really want the directory name of the shell script which is being run:

```
script_dir="$(dirname -- "$(readlink -f -- "$0")")"
```

Yes, it's a bit cludgy, but it's safe.

If you want the current shell, you can try @MichaelMrozek's suggestion of using `$SHELL`.