# How to tell gzip to keep original file?

Tags: command-line, files, gzip

I would like to compress a text file using gzip command line tool while **keeping** the original file. By default running the following command

```
gzip file.txt
```

results in modifying this file and renaming it `file.txt.gz`. instead of this behavior I would like to have this new compressed file in **addition** to the existing one `file.txt`. For now I am using the following command to do that

```
gzip -c file.txt > file.txt.gz
```

It works but I am wondering why there is no easier solution to do such a common task ? Maybe I missed the option doing that ?

Comment: This is because, gzip compresses the given file and creates new file. Compression means squeezing original file and replacing it with new one. Your "-c" option is explicitly telling gzip to save it with other name. That's why it works

Comment: @SHW I didn't get your comment ... ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva once the original file is compressed, it's no longer needed, I guess that was the design.

Comment: Why gzip/gunzip do this *by default* when *no other unix tool does this* is beyond me.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

For GNU `gzip` 1.6 or above, FreeBSD and derivatives or recent versions of NetBSD, see [don_cristi's answer](/a/79411).

With any version, you can use shell redirections as in:

```
gzip < file.txt > file.txt.gz
```

When not given any argument, `gzip` reads its standard input, compresses it and writes the compressed version to its standard output. As a bonus, when using shell redirections, you don't have to worry about files called `"--help"` or `"-"` (that latter one still being a problem for `gzip -c --`).

Another benefit over `gzip -c file.txt > file.txt.gz` is that if `file.txt` can't be opened, the command will fail without creating an empty `file.txt.gz` (or overwriting an existing `file.txt.gz`) and without running `gzip` at all.

A significant difference compared to `gzip -k` though is that there will be no attempt at copying the `file.txt`'s metadata (ownership, permissions, modification time, name of uncompressed file) to `file.txt.gz`.

Also if `file.txt.gz` already existed, it will silently override it unless you have turned the `noclobber` option on in your shell (with `set -o noclobber` for instance in POSIX shells).

Comment: Now this addresses the specifics of the OP's question and answers the general question "How to tell gzip to keep the original file". Very handy and more useful than `-c`.

Comment: Note that the < and > are actually supposed to be typed into the command and are not representing a placeholder for the filename

Comment: What's the `-k` option? Couldn't find it in the man pages, e.g. this version here https://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip. Also, it looks like gzip copies the file's metadata by default.

Comment: @flow2k, that's the link to don_cristi's answer.

Comment: ah, I see it on my macos but too bad it's not on RHEL nor Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: This was ideal for me, and allowed me to one-line my program logic. `gunzip < $log | grep foo | gzip > foo-$log.gz`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Working on gzip version 1.4 as well. `cat file | gzip > file.gz`

Comment: It can be put to `.bashrc` as a small function `gzik(){gzip < ${1} > ${1}.gz}`

Comment: @IsinAltinkaya, `gzik(){gzip < ${1} > ${1}.gz}` is zsh syntax. In `bash`, you need `gzik() { gzip < "$1" > "$1".gz; }`

Answer (score 180):

Note that the recently (June 2013) released [`gzip-1.6`](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7623) *"accepts the --keep (-k) option, for consistency with tools like xz, lzip and bzip2.  With this option, gzip no longer removes named input files when compressing or decompressing"*.

Excerpt from the man page:

> ```
>   -k --keep
>          Keep (don't delete) input files during compression or decompression.
> ```

So, as of `1.6`, you can use `-k` or `--keep` to keep the original file:

```
gzip -k -- "$file"
```

(note that it doesn't work if `$file` is `-` (which `gzip` interprets as meaning *stdin* instead of the actual file called `-`), in which case, you have to change it to `./-`)

That option was [first introduced in the FreeBSD implementation of `gzip`](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/usr.bin/gzip/gzip.c?revision=170053&view=markup) (in FreeBSD 7.0 in 2007) for consistency with `bzip2`. That `gzip` is based on a rewrite of GNU `gzip` by NetBSD. The [`-k` option eventually made it back to NetBSD in 2010](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/usr.bin/gzip/gzip.c?rev=1.98&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&only_with_tag=MAIN).

Comment: Geez. RHEL6 only comes with zip 1.3.12 in base...

Comment: This works on Mac/OS X :) (which is BSD)

Comment: Are there many standard distros not using >= 1.6 anymore? Wondering if answer needs updat

Comment: What is "--" for? I think gzip -k "file" works fine.

Comment: @notilas see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/22142

Comment: @MichaelChirico CentOS 7. :(

Answer (score 31):

From the documentation it seems that there is no option to create a copy of the file.

You can define a shell function

```
gzipkeep() {
    if [ -f "$1" ] ; then
        gzip -c -- "$1" > "$1.gz"
    fi
}
```

and then

```
gzipkeep file.txt
```

Comment: Note that if the file is `-`, you have to call it as `gzipkeep ./-`.

Comment: This is the best solution for scripts IMO, as you can be sure the output file `> "$1.gz"` will exist exactly like specified. Furthermore, you can also specify a different name if the need should arise.

Answer (score 0):

To build on @Matteo's answer, you could make `gzipkeep` able to handle wildcards by surrounding the code in a for loop, preserving the ability that gzip has to handle multiple files at once on a system that lacks that `-k` flag (a huge advantage, otherwise, for `-k`). I also made it verbose so I could see the status of each attempted file:

```
gzipkeep() {
    for file in "$@"; do
        if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
            gzip -cv9 -- "$file" > "$file.gz"
        fi  
    done
}
```

Then just run it with a wildcard. For example:

```
gzipkeep images/*.svg
```