# portable command to unzip and untar on non GNU and old unix

Tags: tar, aix, gzip, hp-ux

On AIX 6.1 without `GNU Tool` installed I have a `.tar.gz` file.
On Ubuntu I would use the very useful command :

```
tar xzf myfile.tar.gz
```

but in this case the `z` switch is not possible.
I do remeber a long time ago a way to use `gzip | tar` but I really can't remember.

Can someone help me with that with a command that could work on almost every system even oldfashion unix ?

Comment: Older Unixes might have a `gzcat` command, so you can do `gzcat myfile.tar.gz | tar xf -`, but really old ones might not have any gzip components installed at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `gzip` feed the uncompressed tar archive to `tar`:

```
gunzip < myfile.tar.gz | tar xvf -
```

(note that it's what GNU `tar` actually does internally, except that it will also report gunzip errors in its exit status).

Use `gzip -d` if `gunzip` is not available. You might also have a `zcat`, but that one may only work with `.Z` files (compressed with `compress` instead of `gzip`).

Comment: You can also replace `tar xvf -` with `pax -rv` (`pax` being the POSIX command to extract `tar` archives)

Comment: My gunzip command is pretty old `gunzip 1.2.4 (18 Aug 93) gunzip [-cdfhlLnNrtvV19] [-S suffix] [file ...]` but say you can put a file after gunzip, what's the difference between `gunzip myfile` and `gunzip < myfile`

Comment: @Kiwy, `gunzip f.gz` unzips `f.gz` onto `f`, `gunzip` without argument uncompresses stdin onto stdout. So `gunzip < f.gz` is like `gunzip -c f.gz` with the benefit that it's the shell that opens the file. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58814/22565

Comment: I guess you should use `gzip -d` instead of gunzip, I already find system that does not has a `gunzip` alias. And also what's the benefit of having the shell opening the file instead of gzip ?

Comment: @Kiwy, no problem for files called `--help` or `-` for instance, consistent error messages, `gzip` not run if the file can't be open... See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58814/22565

Answer (score 0):

You can unzip separately before the tar.

```
gzip -d myfile.tar.gz
tar xvf myfile.tar
```

Comment: No! `gzip -d < myfile.tar.gz | tar xvf -`