# unzip without replacing original file and report to log

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, gzip

I want to write a bash script to decompress a file without overwriting the original one and redirect the operation result into a log file.

I found an answer to the first part of my question at: [How to tell gzip to keep original file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46786/how-to-tell-gzip-to-keep-original-file)

But I cannot report it into a log.

I've tried:

```
gzip -dfv < file.txt.gz > file.txt 2>&1 | tee -a log.txt
```

But it does not redirect operation output to log.txt file.

How can I do that?

Thank you all.

Note: I am working on a Virtual Machine which runs `Ubuntu 10.04` and the installed `gzip 1.3.12` does not offer the `--keep` option. I should avoid updating any package in my system, because it is under strict configuration control and all updates are disabled due to security policies.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `--keep` option? See the second answer. With that it's trivial; just redirect standard output and error in the usual way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited my question explaining why I can't use the `--keep` option.

Comment: You're doing `< file.gz`, that is _stdin_. What exactly do you expect `-v` to print out in that case ?

Comment: "it is under strict configuration control and all updates are disabled due to security policies." Interesting - I've never heard of anything like that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @don_crissti, I'd like the -v option to explain what gzip is doing and I want to redirect it to the log.txt file (e.g. file.txt.gz: --extracted to file.txt or something like that).

Comment: @FaheemMitha, we are using a Virtual Machine that we would like to modify as less as possible. Anyway, if a certain package is necessary to fulfill a requirement (not in this case), it can be added to the machine, as long as the installation package -with its CRC- and documentation on its installation is provided. Having gzip writing to the log file is not a requirement and it is something extra that I'd like to accomplish without having to install a newer version of the package.

Comment: @Alfredo - I know _what you'd like it to do_ - my question was with reference to the definition of `-v` as per the man page: `display the name and percentage reduction for each file...` So when you use `<file` the input is _stdin not a file_ (or more files) so how do you expect it to work ?

Comment: @don_crissti, thank your for your explanation, I guess I was expecting `gzip` to report the name and percentage reduction for each file I passed to it, even with `<file`... I guess this won't happen, since the input is _stdin_. I solved my problem by extracting the file and making a copy of it, since, in this way, I can report each operation into a log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just do this (in Bash) using the `--keep` option.

```
gunzip -vfk file.txt.gz &> file.txt.log
```

The `--keep` option is

```
-k --keep
          Keep (don't delete) input files during compression or decompression.
```

Comment: Even if I cannot apply it in my case, I accept this answer since it would work with last version of `gzip`.