# What does "--" mean in Linux/Unix command line?

Tags: command-line, git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “--” (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean)

`git diff [options] [<commit>] [--] [<path>…]`

In here, how should I understand what [--] means? And when should I use it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As always, you should read a command's manpage to find out how it interprets its arguments.

`--` is commonly used to indicate the end of the command options.  This is especially useful if you want to pass a filename or other argument that begins with `-`.  It's also a good idea to use it before wildcards that might expand to a filename beginning with a hyphen.  (For example, try `mkdir foo; cd foo; echo >-l; ls *; ls -- *`.)

But `git diff` also uses it to indicate whether an argument is a `<commit>` (indicating what revision to diff) or a `<path>` (indicating which file to diff).  It can usually guess, but it's possible for a value to be both a valid commit and a valid path.  In that case, you can use `git diff foo --` to indicate that `foo` is a commit, or `git diff -- foo` to indicate that `foo` is a path.

Answer (score 22):

The `--` is commonly used in command to indicate the end of options. This is useful if your filename begins with a "-" or your input is unknown. Here is an example of its use:

`git diff --stat -- --file1 --file2`

`--file1` is treated as a filename rather than another option.

Comment: +1 for **commonly**. Do note however that many utilities will work just as well with the file specified as `./--file1` etc.