# Why do many CLI apps take a single “--” argument?

Tags: shell, command-line, arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “--” (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean)

There are many command line tools that take a single "--" argument. For example:

```
gem install mysql -- —–with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

It seems to be used as some kind of separator. Does it have a special meaning?
 Is it a commonly used idiom? If so, what's its purpose?

PS: I'm not talking about arguments of the form `--argument`, I'm talking about when you have a `--` followed by white characters and other arguments.

Comment: That dup was already pointed out to you on your SU question. Why did you feel the need to repost here?

Answer (score 0):

`--` is a convention that many programs honor. It means "ignore this argument, and treat all following words as command-line ARGUMENTS rather than command-line OPTIONS. Even if they begin with `-` or `--`."

For instance, if you have the misfortune to have a file named `-f`, how would you delete it? `rm -f` wouldn't work, because the `-f` is interpreted as an option to the `rm` command. But fortunately, the `rm` command honors the `--` convention, so you can delete that file using:

```
rm -- -f
```