# How to remove/rename file which contains special character eg. "-x" using command line

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “--” (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean)

Can anybody explain me below things

i have file named "-xyz".
if i try to remove or move that file using command line , it's unable to move.
i tried below things :

```
[rahul@srv100 ~]# ls -lrt  -- "-xyz"
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahul rahul 0 Dec 19 08:06 -xyz
[rahul@srv100 ~]# mv "-xyz" xyz
mv: invalid option -- x
Try `mv --help' for more information.
[rahul@srv100 ~]# mv \-xyz xyz
mv: invalid option -- x
Try `mv --help' for more information.
[rahul@srv100 ~]# mv -\xyz xyz
mv: invalid option -- x
Try `mv --help' for more information.
[rahul@srv100 ~]# mv '-xyz' xyz
mv: invalid option -- x
Try `mv --help' for more information.
```

finally i rename that file using winscp, and after trying multiple ways i got one option and it's working.

```
mv -- '-xyz' xyz
```

Wish the help of "--", i created file/directory  as below

```
mkdir -- --abc
touch -- -xyz
```

So my Question is what is this "--" in bash ?
Please explain.

Comment: For info, `--` has nothing to do with bash. In your case, you can also use `./-xyz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already mentioned `--` is used to delimit options from arguments. If you execute a program and specify any arguments the program has no way of distinguishing if the specified arguments should be interpreted as a command line option or an argument. That is the reason why a prefix for options was introduced `-` / `--` or `/` on windows, i.e. `-rf`,`--help` or `/?`

As you may have files beginning with a such an prefix or any other special name which could be interpreted `--` was introduced to delimit command line options from normal arguments, i.e. every argument after `--` will not be treated as a command line option but just as a argument. [`getopt (1)`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=getopt&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en), a standard solution to parse arguments, for example supports the `--` delimiter which means any program using `getopt` automatically supports the `--` delimiter.

If you want to work with files starting with special characters like `-` you can also just add `./` in front of them as they now don't start with `-` so they won't be interpreted as command line option, for your example it would be `mkdir ./--abc`

Answer (score 1):

This is used to tell the command that after that point no more command options are accepted.

So

> rm -- -abc

means that it will ignore the - from the abc.

for more information you can refer to:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html

Comment: Not really _ignore_ the `-` from the `-abc`. Instead, it will not consider `-abc` to be an option, since after the `--`, no more options are interpreted, only arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It's an indicator to the individual commands to stop interpreting further command line arguments as options.