# explain the command `printf -- "#!${opt_E}"`

Tags: shell-script, command

I am not able to understand this command and getting confused :
here are things i executed on linux trying to undertand its working

```
[root@testgfs2 final_scripts]# printf -- "#!${opt_E}"
printf -- "#reset{opt_E}"
#reset{opt_E}[root@testgfs2 final_scripts]# printf -- "#!${opt_E}"
printf -- "#"#reset{opt_E}"{opt_E}"
##reset{opt_E}{opt_E}[root@testgfs2 final_scripts]# echo !$
echo "#"#reset{opt_E}"{opt_E}"
##reset{opt_E}{opt_E}
```

how does this work and i don't know under what topic it comes so i am unable to find it on google also.

also what does `--` doing after printf

Comment: See [What does “--” (double-dash) mean?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean).

Comment: Note that `!` is reinterpreted by Bash, so try using `dash` or some other shell that doesn't do *history expansion*.

Comment: The correct way to write it would have been `printf '#!%s' "$opt_E"` BTW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Designators):

> !!:$
>
> designates the last argument of the preceding command. This may be shortened to !$.

If this behavior is undesired you can just escape ! with backslash:

```
% echo "\!$"                  
!$
```

Answer (score 2):

In a script, the characters `#!` are not special in this context. The snippet `printf -- "#!${opt_E}"` calls the `printf` command with two arguments: `--`, and `#!` concatenated with the value of the `opt_E` variable. The argument `--` tells `printf` that even if there are subsequent arguments beginning with `-`, they are not to be interpreted as options; it doesn't make a difference here since `#!${opt_E}` doesn't begin with `-`. The double quotes around `#!${opt_E}` protect `#` from being interpreted as a comment start character, and they protect the value of `opt_E` from being split into separate words which are interpreted as wildcard patterns.

If the value of `opt_E` doesn't contain any `%` or `\` character, then this command prints `#!` followed by the value of `opt_E`, with no final newline. In general, the command interprets the value of `opt_E` as a printf format.

If you try this out in an interactive shell, you may see strange effects due to `!` being interpreted as a history expansion character, which automatically recalls previous commands. To avoid this, add a `\` before `!`. `!` is also interpreted literally within single quotes: `printf -- '#!${opt_E}'`.

If you're replaying a script, you'll have to have set `opt_E` to the right value first. If you're trying to debug a script, add `set -x` on the second line (insert it just below the initial `#!` line): the shell will print a trace of each line as it executes it.