# Passing named arguments to shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, arguments

Is there any easy way to pass (receive) named parameters to a shell script?

For example,

```
my_script -p_out '/some/path' -arg_1 '5'
```

And inside `my_script.sh` receive them as:

```
# I believe this notation does not work, but is there anything close to it?
p_out=$ARGUMENTS['p_out']
arg1=$ARGUMENTS['arg_1']

printf "The Argument p_out is %s" "$p_out"
printf "The Argument arg_1 is %s" "$arg1"
```

Is this possible in Bash or Zsh?

Comment: have a look at [docopt](http://docopt.org/) – it helps with named parameters and does input validation, too

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499472/specify-command-line-arguments-like-name-value-pairs-for-shell-script

Comment: Just wondering, why is this preferable to using env vars? `P_OUT='/some/path' ARG_1=5 my_script` works with no extra steps. You can reference the env vars directly in the script, with defaults, error handling for missing values etc. I'm trying to imagine why the extra effort for command-line params is worthwhile.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

If you don't mind being limited to single-letter argument names i.e. `my_script -p '/some/path' -a5`, then in bash you could use the built-in `getopts`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":a:p:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a) arg_1="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    p) p_out="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    \?) echo "Invalid option -$OPTARG" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
  esac

  case $OPTARG in
    -*) echo "Option $opt needs a valid argument"
    exit 1
    ;;
  esac
done

printf "Argument p_out is %s\n" "$p_out"
printf "Argument arg_1 is %s\n" "$arg_1"
```

Then you can do

```
$ ./my_script -p '/some/path' -a5
Argument p_out is /some/path
Argument arg_1 is 5
```

There is a helpful [Small getopts tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20230324055145/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php?id=howto:getopts_tutorial&rev=1521590837) or you can type `help getopts` at the shell prompt.

Edit: The second `case` statement in `while` loop triggers if the `-p` option has no arguments and is followed by another option, e.g. `my_script -p -a5`, and `exit`s the program.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but why only 1 letter for the arguments?

Comment: I implemented this (but with `i` and `d`). When I run it with `my_script -i asd -d asd` I get an empty string for the `d` argument. When I run it `my_script -d asd -i asd` I get empty string for both arguments.

Comment: @Milkncookiez -- I had a similar problem -- I didn't include a ':' after the last argument (a 'w' in my case). Once I added the ':' it started working as expected

Comment: @KaushikGhose Just fixed it. I guess better late than never. I wish SO notified you when an answer other than the one you accepted got more accepted votes.

Comment: Arguably there's a second answer using getopt (no s) for long args.  I'm not experienced to write it though.

Comment: @Kevin, I think because passing multi-char strings in the colon-separated getopts list somehow makes them read as a command? I get "<multi-char flag>: command not found" error when I try.

Comment: Dead tutorial link.

Comment: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20230324055145/http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) to archived version of the getopts tutorial.

Comment: @FernandoCostaBertoldi thank you - I have edited that link into the answer

Answer (score 94):

This is not a parser for positioned arguments, is for `key=value aa=bb` arguments;

```
for ARGUMENT in "$@"
do
   KEY=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f1 -d=)

   KEY_LENGTH=${#KEY}
   VALUE="${ARGUMENT:$KEY_LENGTH+1}"

   export "$KEY"="$VALUE"
done

# use here your expected variables
echo "STEPS = $STEPS"
echo "REPOSITORY_NAME = $REPOSITORY_NAME"
echo "EXTRA_VALUES = $EXTRA_VALUES"
```

**Usage**

```
bash args_shell_parser.sh STEPS="ABC" REPOSITORY_NAME="stackexchange" \
           EXTRA_VALUES="KEY1=VALUE1 KEY2=VALUE2"
```

**Console result:**

```
STEPS = ABC
REPOSITORY_NAME = stackexchange
EXTRA_VALUES = KEY1=VALUE1 KEY2=VALUE2
```

**Features:**

- It does not matter what **order** the arguments are in
- Explicit declaration of all variables are not required
- values could have **spaces**.
- It handles complex cases, when the argument value contains "=" sign

Put this snippet at the start of your script.

Prior version of this script:

- [v1](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/c0047f58cb6765c7b6a7fb33c466ab3f#file-args_shell_parser-v1-0-0-md)

Comment: This is a neat solution, but it seems to take a long time to parse, like 5 to 10 seconds on my PC, is this normal behavior?

Comment: mmm in my case it is instantaneous.

Comment: This is neat but assumes you have `=` delimiter between the key and the value. I.e. you can't pass a value with a space like so: `-p 3000` or `--port 3000`

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks if the value has an equals in it like this

MYVAR="PROPERTIES_LIST":"\"apim=true&whichvalue=345\""

Comment: several systems will have problems with a variable like that. An equivalent could be `PROPERTIES_LIST=apim:true&whichvalue:345`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion #BohdanShulha It had an error. I fixed: https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/c0047f58cb6765c7b6a7fb33c466ab3f#file-suggestion-history-md

Comment: export "${KEY,,}"="$VALUE" - to make variable/parameter names not case sensitive

Comment: This is gonna fail if you pass new line literal. Example: `bash args_shell_parser.sh STEPS="\nABC"` Do you know a way to resolve this?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is for simple key-value params. I dont' tested but maybe you could escape it : STEPS="\\nABC"

Comment: You can also support passing argument names with an optional `--` prefix (e.g. `--profile=test`) if you add `[[ $KEY == --* ]] && KEY=${KEY:2}` right before the `export "$KEY"="$VALUE"` line.

Comment: Can I use default values here?

Comment: Interesting. I think the only way could be set some values at the beginning. Check this https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/c0047f58cb6765c7b6a7fb33c466ab3f#file-args_shell_parser-default-md

Comment: support passing argument names with an optional -- prefix could use `for ARGUMENT in "$@";do  export $(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f1 -d=|cut -d '-' -f 3)=${ARGUMENT:$(echo  $ARGUMENT | cut -f1 -d=|wc -L)+1}; done`

Answer (score 75):

I stole this from [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924), but you could do something like this:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    --p_out=*)
      p_out="${1#*=}"
      ;;
    --arg_1=*)
      arg_1="${1#*=}"
      ;;
    *)
      printf "***************************\n"
      printf "* Error: Invalid argument.*\n"
      printf "***************************\n"
      exit 1
  esac
  shift
done
```

The only caveat is that you have to use the syntax `my_script --p_out=/some/path --arg_1=5`.

Comment: The caveat is not necessary. :) You can have the conditions as follows: `-c|--condition)`

Comment: [Docs to truncate string in variable](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#:~:text=parameter%23) (and to continue the trend in this thread, this should be the accepted answer).

Comment: @Milkncookiez: I am a noob, can you make the full code? Thanks!

Comment: @LeQuangNam In the example above, change `--p_out` to `-p|--p_out`

Answer (score 47):

The probably closest syntax to that is:

```
p_out='/some/path' arg_1='5' my_script
```

## Update 1

Nearly a decade later I realize that it gets much closer than that (not sure whether it already was back then).

```
man -P 'less -p "^\s+set \["' bash
```

> ```
> set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [-o option-name] [--] [-] [arg ...]
>
> -k
> ```
>
> All arguments in the form of assignment statements are placed in the environment for a command, not just those that precede the command name.

So you can do this, too:

```
set -k
my_script p_out='/some/path' arg_1='5'
```

A bit more complicated but safer:

```
if [[ $- =~ k ]]; then
    # set -k has already been set so no need to reverse it after the command
    my_script p_out='/some/path' arg_1='5'
else
    set -k
    my_script p_out='/some/path' arg_1='5'
    set +k
fi
```

You can test this with:

```
set -k
echo "\$foo: '$foo'"; bash -c 'echo $foo' foo=bar
```

Comment: Related to this, if the `-k` option is set in the *calling* shell, then `my_script p_out='/some/path' arg_1='5'` has the same effect. (All arguments in the form of an assignment are added to the environment, not just those assignments preceding the command.)

Comment: @chepner, Hi, I like your solution, but I don't know where to put the '-k' option as you mentioned, can you show me the code? thanks

Comment: @StayFoolish One way would be to run `set -k`, then run `my_script p_out='/some/path' arg_1='5'`.

Comment: This is by far the easiest (and imho best) solution. It's idiomatic bash, and you don't need any parser logic which is just needless complexity (and hard to reuse).

Comment: @GerardvanHelden See my edit.

Comment: Remember to call `set +k` when finish calling the command, otherwise, you can face the problem when using Bash completion.

Comment: @LeQuangNam And you should not even do that unconditionally... ;-)

Answer (score 22):

I just came up with this script

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do

   if [[ $1 == *"--"* ]]; then
        v="${1/--/}"
        declare $v="$2"
   fi

  shift
done
```

pass it like `my_script --p_out /some/path --arg_1 5` and then in the script you can use `$arg_1` and `$p_out`.

Comment: I like this solution in KSH88 I had to `v=``echo ${1} | awk '{print substr($1,3)}'``
 typeset $v="$2"` (Remove one backtick each side)

Comment: perfection, thanks

Comment: NB `shift` removes the 1st argument from the start of the args list

Comment: Should also `shift` within the `if` since you've consumed 2 args, right?

Answer (score 22):

I found [the solution from cdmo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204927/206759) the best, because it is not only limited to a single letter. With a slight adjustment it will consume either whitespace separated arguments like `--url www.example.com` and those with an assignment like, for example the synonym parameter `-u=www.example.com`. Even flag arguments can be parsed:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    --url*|-u*)
      if [[ "$1" != *=* ]]; then shift; fi # Value is next arg if no `=`
      URL="${1#*=}"
      ;;
    --file*|-f*)
      if [[ "$1" != *=* ]]; then shift; fi
      FILE="${1#*=}"
      ;;
    --help|-h)
      printf "Meaningful help message" # Flag argument
      exit 0
      ;;
    *)
      >&2 printf "Error: Invalid argument\n"
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
  shift
done
```

Answer (score 21):

> **CAVEAT**
> The solution below does not check for incomplete / malformed command invocation! For example, if `--p_out` requires an argument, but the command is called as `my-script.sh --p_out --arg_1 27` then it will happily assign the string `"--arg_1"` to the `p_out` variable.

This answer was initially an edit of [@cdmo's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204927/85131) (thanks to @Milkncookiez's comment also!), that got rejected as expected.

When using the variables, one can make sure that they have a default value set by using `"${p_out:-"default value"}"` for example.

From [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-parameter-expansion) of the GNU Bash manual:

> **`${parameter:-word}`**
> If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    -p|-p_out|--p_out)
      p_out="$2"
      ;;
    -a|-arg_1|--arg_1)
      arg_1="$2"
      ;;
    *)
      printf "***************************\n"
      printf "* Error: Invalid argument.*\n"
      printf "***************************\n"
      exit 1
  esac
  shift
  shift
done

# Example of using the saved command line arguments.
# WARNING: Any of these may be an empty string, if the corresponding
#          option was not supplied on the command line!

echo "Without default values:"
echo "p_out: ${p_out}"
echo "arg_1: ${arg_1}"; echo

# Example of using parsed command line arguments with DEFAULT VALUES.
# (E.g., to avoid later commands being blown up by "empty" variables.)

echo "With default values:"
echo "p_out: ${p_out:-\"27\"}"
echo "arg_1: ${arg_1:-\"smarties cereal\"}"
```

If the above script is saved into `my-script.sh`, then these invocations are all equivalent:

```
$ . my-script.sh -a "lofa" -p "miez"
$ . my-script.sh -arg_1 "lofa" --p_out "miez"
$ . my-script.sh --arg_1 "lofa" -p "miez"
```

(where `.` is Bash's [`source`](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html) command.)

To demonstrate the default values part, here's the output without any arguments given:

```
$ . my-script.sh
Without default values:
p_out:
arg_1:

With default values:
p_out: "27"
arg_1: "smarties cereal"
```

Answer (score 18):

With `zsh`, you'd use [`zparseopts`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-zparseopts):

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/zutil
zparseopts -A ARGUMENTS -p_out: -arg_1:

p_out=$ARGUMENTS[--p_out]
arg1=$ARGUMENTS[--arg_1]

printf 'Argument p_out is "%s"\n' "$p_out"
printf 'Argument arg_1 is "%s"\n' "$arg_1"
```

But you'd call the script with `myscript --p_out foo`.

Note that `zparseopts` doesn't support abbreviating long options or the `--p_out=foo` syntax like GNU `getopt(3)` does.

Comment: Do you know why the zparseopts uses just one dash for the arguments whereas in the `[]` it is 2 dashes? Does not make sense!

Comment: @Timo, see `info zsh zparseopts` for details

Answer (score 4):

I have just made this one.
It doesn't require "=" and supports non-valued parameters.
Mind the need of additional `shift` commands for valued parameters.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    printf "Utilizacao:\n"
    printf "$0 [[--imagem_inicial|-i] <tag_inicial>] [[--imagem_final|-f] <tag_final>] [--verbose|-v]\n"
    exit 1
fi

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    --imagem_inicial|-i)
      export tag_imagem_inicial="${2}"
      shift
      ;;
    --imagem_final|-f)
      export tag_imagem_final="${2}"
      shift
      ;;
    --verbose|-v)
      export verbose_option=1
      ;;
    *)
      printf "ERRO: Parametros invalidos\n"
      printf "Execute sem parametros para a sintaxe.\n"
      exit 1
  esac
  shift
done

echo tag_imagem_inicial=${tag_imagem_inicial}
echo tag_imagem_final=${tag_imagem_final}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a combination of some approaches recommended here. In my case, I need a script that could handle arguments in this format: `--arg1=test`
So I used the following:

```bsh
args=()

for argument in "$@"
do

    key=$(echo $argument | cut -f1 -d=)
    value=$(echo $argument | cut -f2 -d=)   

    if [[ $key == *"--"* ]]; then
        v="${key/--/}"
        declare $v="${value}" 
   fi
done

args+=( '--local_dir' ${local_dir})
args+=( '--format' ${format})

python3 ./test.py "${args[@]}"
```

You can see that I added the arguments together to call a python script with those arguments:
`test_script.sh --local_dir=test --format=other`

Thanks to Shahzad Malik and JRichardsz, for the guide to join the two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I want the script to function consistently with other utilities, providing the least surprise to the user. Here is what I came up with, combining several ideas here (especially the answer from cdmo) and some additional research. It has the following features:

- Only accepts known named parameters.
- Accepts positional parameters as well.
- Named parameters can be in any order.
- Named (so-called ["long parameters"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/573378)) can be in the form `foo=bar` or `--foo bar`.
- `--help` is recognized.
- `--` is recognized to signal [remaining parameters are all positional parameters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382).

Let's assume we have the following command, accepting three positional parameters and a named `foo` parameter:

> `munge [--foo=bar] x y z`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

usage() {
  echo 'Usage: munge [--foo=bar] <x> <y> <z>' >&2
}

args=()
foo="default value"
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
### start custom parameter checks
    --foo=*)
      foo="${1#*=}"
      shift
      ;;
    --foo*)
      foo="$2"
      shift
      shift
      ;;
### end custom parameter checks
    --help)
      usage
      exit 0
      ;;
    --)
      shift
      while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do args+=("$1"); shift; done;
      break;
      ;;
    --*)
      echo "**Bad parameter: $1**" >&2
      usage
      exit 1
      ;;
    *)
      args+=("$1");
      shift
      ;;
  esac
done

if [[ ${#args[@]} -ne 3 ]]; then
  echo "**Incorrect number of arguments: ${#args[@]}**" >&2
  usage
  exit 1
fi

# test
echo foo: $foo
echo arg 1: ${args[0]}
echo arg 2: ${args[1]}
echo arg 3: ${args[2]}
```

This accepts the following:

- `munge blah blah blah`
- `munge --foo=bar blah blah blah`
- `munge --foo bar blah blah blah`
- `munge --foo=bar -- blah blah blah`
- `munge --foo bar -- blah blah blah`
- `munge blah --foo=bar blah blah`
- `munge blah --foo bar blah blah`
- …
- `munge blah blah blah --foo=bar`
- `munge blah blah blah --foo bar`

Caveats:

- The program must henceforth use the `args` array (e.g. `{$args[0]}`) rather than `$*` (e.g. `$1`) and the like.
- Usage is always sent to `stderr`, when for `--help` it should more correctly be sent to `stdout`.
- If a known long parameter comes at the end without the value, the error message will say `$2: unbound variable` instead of something useful. (The additional error handling would just be too verbose for the benefit.)

Yeah, it's verbose and clumsy, but it is most consistent with other CLI utilities. Bash really needs something better. It this area Bash is really pitiful in comparison to PowerShell (which of course has its own problems).

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on that of JRichardsz, but fixing a few issues and adding more transparency about what's actually going on − I'm not a fan of "copy this random code that you don't understand, and run it on your personal computer. I swear it's safe" :P

```bsh
for argument in "$@"
do
  key=$(echo $argument | cut --fields 1 --delimiter='=')
  value=$(echo $argument | cut --fields 2 --delimiter='=')

  case "$key" in
    "wallet")        wallet="$value" ;;
    "network")       network="$value" ;;
    *)
  esac
done

echo "We'll be using wallet $wallet and network $network"
```

Invoking this script can be done as:

```bsh
myScript.sh wallet=myWallet.json network=https://granadanet.smartpy.io
```

Answer (score -2):

If a function or an application has more than zero arguments, it always has a last argument.

If you want to read option flag and value pairs, as in:
`$ ./t.sh -o output -i input -l last`

And you want to accept a variable number of option/value pairs,

And do not want a huge "if .. then .. else .. fi" tree,

Then after checking for an argument count of non-zero and even,

Write a while loop with these four eval statements as the body, followed by a case statement using the two values determined in each pass through the loop.

The tricky part of the scripting is demonstrated here:

```
#!/bin/sh    

# For each pair - this chunk is hard coded for the last pair.
eval TMP="'$'$#"
eval "PICK=$TMP"
eval TMP="'$'$(($#-1))"
eval "OPT=$TMP"

# process as required - usually a case statement on $OPT
echo "$OPT \n $PICK"

# Then decrement the indices (as in third eval statement) 

:<< EoF_test
$ ./t.sh -o output -i input -l last
-l 
last
$ ./t.sh -o output -l last
-l 
last
$ ./t.sh  -l last
-l 
last
EoF_test
```

Answer (score -2):

function satunnaisluku () { let $1=$RANDOM ;}; satunnaisluku apu; satunnaisluku kipu; echo $apu; echo $kipu

- there are *several* other methods to use nameparameters. Forexample method to find maximum from matrix:

function haemaksimi () { maksimi=$(echo $(sort -n <(declare -p $1 | tr ' ' '\n' | tr -dc '\n'[0-9])) |  sed 's/.* //') ;} ; apu=""; for n in {1..10000}; do apu=$apu" "$RANDOM$RANDOM; done; unset maksimi; time haemaksimi matrix; echo $maksimi

---

I have made IDE for BASH-scripting to myself - some few thousand lines - and I have used a function like those for ten years - for reading items in different tasks in the same session - nowadays my days are full of scripting because a busted leg.

If you use something very heavily for ten years and it always operates impeccably without doing any harm to other programs isn't it quite the same how it is called?

I stumble constantly to warnings: BASH cannot do that ... Sour grapes I say.

Comment: 1) see the [editing help about code formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help), 2) properly indenting the code would make it far, far easier to read for others, 3) `echo $(foo)` is usually unnecessary, it's almost the same as just `foo`, except for some shell oddities. I don't know if you're relying on those, since 4) there's really no description of the code here, which makes it harder to figure out what you're showing. 5) `function foo()` is non-standard, and usually better written as just `foo()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```
mitsos@redhat24$ my_script "a=1;b=mitsos;c=karamitsos"
#!/bin/sh
eval "$1"
```

you've just injected command line parameters inside script scope !!

Comment: This doesn't work with the syntax the OP specified; they want `-a 1 -b mitsos -c karamitsos`