# Do command line options take an equals sign between option name and value?

Tags: command-line, options

Just using `kubectl` as an example, I note that

```
kubectl run --image nginx ...
```

and

```
kubectl run --image=nginx ...
```

both work.

For command-line programs in general, is there a rule about whether an equals sign is allowed/required between the option name and the value?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In general, the implementation of how command-line arguments are interpreted is left completely at the discretion of the programmer.

That said, *in many cases*, the value of a "long" option (such as is introduced with `--option_name`) is specified with an `=` between the option name and the value (i.e. `--option_name=value`), whereas for single-letter options it is more customary to separate the flag and value with a space, such as `-o value`, or use no separation at all (as in `-oValue`).

An example from the man-page of the GNU date utility:

> ```
>   -d, --date=STRING
>         display time described by STRING, not 'now'
> ```

> ```
>   -f, --file=DATEFILE
>         like --date; once for each line of DATEFILE
> ```

As you can see, the value would be separated by a space from the option switch when using the "short" form (i.e. `-d`), but by an `=` when using the "long" form (i.e. `--date`).

**Edit**

As pointed out by Stephen Kitt, the [GNU coding standard](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces) recommends the use of  `getopt` and `getopt_long` to parse command-line options. The man-page of `getopt_long` states:

> A long option may take a parameter, of the form `--arg=param` or `--arg param`.

So, a program using that function will accept both forms.

Comment: libpopt erroneously printed the equals sign against short options, resulting in usage messages that were not actually the command-line syntax accepted by the program.  http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/libpopt/

Comment: Maybe getopt can be treated as a reference point, if not a standard so that  allowing either with or without the equals sign is normal  with long options; with short options, no equals sign is used.

Comment: Yes, I think it is reasonably safe to say so.

Comment: @JdeBP fyi, the 1st link on your libpopt page is broken

Answer (score 10):

> For command-line programs in general, is there a rule about whether
>     an equals sign is allowed/required between the switch and the value?

No, there isn't. There are many competing standards in the open source
world and computing in general ([obligatory
xkcd](https://xkcd.com/927/)) and everyone can come up with new rules and
standards any time they want.  [POSIX Utility Argument
Syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html)
for example doesn't mention `=` at all for example while [man
getopt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) mentions
it.  In practice you can come across all kinds of command line
programs:

Those that take long option value after `=` or after a whitespace:

```
$ touch a b c d
$ ls --format=verbose
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 17 14:39 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 17 14:39 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 17 14:39 c
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 17 14:39 d
$ ls --format verbose
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 17 14:39 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 17 14:39 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 17 14:39 c
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Mar 17 14:39 d
```

Those that do not take long option value after `=` but require a
whitespace:

```
$ readelf  -a main | grep  'program interpreter'
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
$ patchelf --set-interpreter=fake main
patchelf: getting info about '--set-interpreter=fake': No such file or directory
$ patchelf --set-interpreter fake main
$ readelf  -a main | grep  'program interpreter'
      [Requesting program interpreter: fake]
```

Those that take value after `=` but do not take options with `-` or
  `--`:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=~/Desktop/test.txt bs=1M count=3
```

There can be many reasons for a which a given command line program
accepts input in a given way: author's vision, because nobody cares,
because author didn't know that someone else has already come up with
a standard, because program has been ported onto Unix from different
operating system with completely different conventions or [has been made to look like it has
been](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)#History).

Comment: Wow, allowing options without the dash/double-dash is a mess.

Comment: @JoshuaFox: yep, it is. Ideally, you should always read manual before using a new command to know how it behaves.

Comment: I think that `dd` is a redherring and bringing it up is only muddling the point, as those `foo=bar` of `dd` are _operands_ not options. There are other programs which use arguments of the `key=value` form (`awk`, `make`, `env`, etc), and they may also accept _options_/switches (= command line arguments starting with a dash). Standard `dd` does not accept any command line [_options_](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html#tag_20_31_04), though GNU `dd` does (2 options: `--help` and `--version`).

Comment: @mosvy: `man dd` from coreutils mentions both operands and options, `man dd` on FreeBSD uses "operand" and "option"  interchangeably and I really don't understand what's the difference between operands and options - I guess that maybe GNU people used the term `operand` for historical compatibility as they don't start with a minus.

Comment: And `patchelf` does not accept `--set-interpreter=bar` because it's hand-parsing the options, instead of using getopt_long. Other examples which use long options and do NOT follow the GNU convention are classical Xtoolkit & other [X11 apps](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=X&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=FreeBSD+12.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html#OPTIONS)

Comment: @mosvy: yes, I know, parsing in `patchelf` is done in `src/patchelf.cc`. You mention it because you think this information should be added to my answer?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk the options accepted by GNU dd are `--help` and `--version`, as already mentioned. The difference between options and other arguments/operands/etc is made by the standard, I didn't invented it ;-)

Comment: I mention all that because I consider it relevant and interesting.

Comment: @mosvy: what standard? If it's GNU, ok, they may have a standard. I tried to be clear in my answer and let user know that they may be multiple standards for the same thing. See `dd` manpage from FreeBSD: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dd(1). They use `operand` and `option` interchangeably. It doesn't matter in the long run but only because GNU people have come up with some standard does not mean that the world will follow.

Comment: "what standard?" POSIX, see my 1st [options](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html#tag_20_31_04) link above. AFAIK GNU dd conforms to it, though it implements its own extensions.

Comment: @mosvy: the page you linked to clearly says that `dd` doesn't understand *options* as understood by POSIX. Other standards/people may have a different understanding of what *option* means. FWIW, in my answer I've also linked to POSIX standard that doesn't even mention `option=val` even though many programs accept it, not only GNU ones. That's the thing with the standards - there are many of them and they commonly contradict each other.

Comment: The GNU standard and other conventions followed by BSDs or other Unix systems in this matter do not contradict the POSIX standard AFAIK. Please do not equivocate just to "win" what you think is an "argument": of course there are a lot of other meanings of the word "options" (eg. "stock options"), but here "command line options/flags/switches" = "command line arguments starting with a dash". [Reference](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_01).

Comment: @mosvy: I'm not trying to win a discussion that cannot be won because we're not discussing something precise enough to define it clearly. FreeBSD dd manpage and Wikipedia article I linked to in my answer say *option* sometimes when referring to dd *operands* and it's good as long as long user understands what it means in the given case.

Comment: You should submit a documentation bug report to FreeBSD, and edit the Wikipedia, and make them use a consistent terminology.