# purpose of dashes in `wget -qO- https://get.speedify.com | bash -`

Tags: bash, wget, dash

In this command:

```bsh
wget -qO- https://get.speedify.com | bash -
```

Source: https://support.speedify.com/article/562-install-speedify-linux

...the first `-q` is the option for "quiet" mode. What is the `O-` (notice that is the letter "O", NOT a zero) part though? Why the letter O? Why the trailing `-`? Finally, after the `bash` command there is also a trailing `-`. Why?

Update: now that I know that is the letter O, NOT a zero, I see this from the `man wget` manual pages:

> ```
>   -O file
>   --output-document=file
>       The documents will not be written to the appropriate
>       files, but all will be concatenated together and written
>       to file.  If - is used as file, documents will be
>       printed to standard output, disabling link conversion.
> ```

So, `-qO` is the same as `-q -O`, and `-O` sets the output file, and `-O-` apparently says to print the document to standard output. I wonder why they didn't do `-O=-` or `-O -` though...?

**Not a duplicate:**

This question answers the smallest, least-relevant, and least-significant part of my question: [Do command line options take an equals sign between option name and value?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/573377/do-command-line-options-take-an-equals-sign-between-option-name-and-value). It does *not* answer my question.

Comment: - is stadin/stdout Here is a deeper answer. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/usage-of-dash-in-place-of-a-filename

Comment: I actually wondered why that commands lacks a `sudo` before `bash` (without `sudo`, you can't be sure you achieve the maximum of damage possible when blindly running commands off the internet). But no problem, it's all there on the linked page ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there are 3 questions you are looking for answers about. Let me take them in turn.

1. As you identified from the man page, the `-` when used as the filename to write to will indicate `stdout`.
2. In the `bash` portion of the command, the `-` is used as the name of the file to read from. In this case, it tells it to read from `stdin`. Since the two commands are piped together, it will be reading what is being written to `stdout` from step 1.
3. Finally, the reason that it isn't `-O=-` is because of the way `getopt` from the standard C library works when parsing command line options. When you have single letter option that take no parameters (e.g., `-v` for verbose and `-r` for recursive) you can specify them individually (`-v -r`) or as a block (`-vr`) and you use only a single dash before them. If a single letter option takes a parameter (e.g., `-w <outfile>`) then `getopt` expects the next thing after the option to be parameter. So `-w foo` and `-wfoo` are the same in that they write to the file `foo`. However, `-vw foo` and `-wv foo` would be interpreted differently. `-vw foo` would be verbose and write to the file foo, but `-wv foo` would write to the file `v` and have `foo` as an additional command line argument.

Long arguments are specified by two dashes at the start. When processing those arguments, it expects the parameter to be after an `=` sign. If you look back at the quoted section from wget, you see that it tells you `-O file` for the "short" version of the option and `--output-documet=file` for the long version.

Comment: What about `-O -` (having the space after the `O` and before the final `-`)? Is that valid? Why or why not?

Comment: @GabrielStaples try it. It's valid all right.