# Help understanding Bash command-line argument parsing code

Tags: bash, arguments

I want to take two arguments and a third optional one for a script I am developing. I am new working with bash so I have been copying and trying to understand the following code that does what I want (I guess)

```
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
   case $1 in
   -f1|-fasta1)
       FASTA1=$2
       shift
       ;;
   -f1=*|-fasta1=*)
       FASTA1=${1#*=}
       ;;
   -d|-directory)
       DIRECTORY=$2
       shift
       ;;
   -d=*|-directory=*)
       DIRECTORY=${1#*=}
       ;;
   -f2|fasta2)
       FASTA2=$2
       shift
       ;;
   -f2=*|-fasta2=*)
       FASTA2=${1#*=}
       ;;
   -*)
       echo "Invalid option: $1" >&2
       exit 1
       ;;
   --)
       # Do FILES+=("${@:2}") maybe
       break
       ;;
   *)
       # TODO
       # Do FILES+=("$1") maybe
       ;;
   esac

   shift
done
```

The thing is that there is many part of this code that I dont really understand what is for for instance the  `-gt`  or the `1#*=` or why each argument needs to be written twice line
one

```
-f1|-fasta1)
       FASTA1=$2
       shift
```

and two

```
 -f1=*|-fasta1=*)
       FASTA1=${1#*=}
```

Someone could tell me where I can find explanation for this. I have been reading in tutorial but with easier examples I cant understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are posting is indeed a very "manual" way of parsing command-line arguments. It is usually considered good practice to use `getopt` and/or `getopt_long` for that purpose. Note also that having "long options" introduced by only one dash (as in `-fasta1`) is unusual; normally you would expect them to be preceded by two dashes (see also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/573377/377345) on the format of command-line arguments).

That said, most of what you are seeing is basic shell syntax, namely [string manipulation](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion), [`case` statements](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Choices_.28case_and_select.29) and [test constructs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29).

The `[[ $# -gt 0 ]]` statement is simply a test in which the special paramter `$#`, containing the number of command-line arguments, is checked whether it is greater than (`-gt`) zero. This is used as condition in the `while` loop because the parameter handling routine uses the `shift` statements that discards the first command-line parameter after it is processed, thereby reducing the number of arguments successively. Once all parameters are processed, the option handling loop needs to finish.

As for the other questions: The program wants to allow the user to specify the first FASTA file in a variable of possible syntaxes, namely:

```
-f1 <filename>
-fasta1 <filename>
-f1=<filename>
-fasta1=<filename>
```

The program does so by iterating over the command-line parameters "manually", i.e. it always checks what the "current first" argument (`$1`) is, interprets it, and then discards it using the `shift` command (whereby all command-line arguments move "one number up").

In order to accept both the "short" and "long" option names, the `case` statement accepts both `-f1` and `-fasta1` (for the space-separated syntax), and both `-f1=*` and `-fasta1=*` (for the `=`-separated syntax) as current argument. However, it needs to treat the "value" part of the option differently depending on the syntax.

- For the space-separated syntax, the statement of the first FASTA file is recognized by `$1` being either `-f1` or `-fasta1`. The program knows that the "value" of the option is then in the next command-line parameter `$2`, so it assigns the content of `$2` to the `FASTA1` variable. An additional `shift` is needed to discard that next command-line parameter, too, since it is already handled in this iteration.
- For the `=`-separated syntax, the statement of the first FASTA file is recognized by `$1` matching either `-f1=*` or `-fasta1=*`. This means that the "value" of the option is part of the current value of `$1` and needs to be extracted by string manipulation. The statement

  ```bash
  ${variablename#pattern}
  ```

  means "return the value of `$variablename`, but remove the shortest string that matches `pattern` *from the beginning* of the value". So,

  ```bash
  ${1#*=}
  ```

  means "return the value of `$1`, but remove the shortest string that matches `*=` from the beginning", effectively stripping `-f1=` or `-fasta1=` from the value. What remains is the filename.

If you want to dive deeper into shell programming, I would recommend [GreyCat&Lhunath's Bash Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) for further reading.