# Tmux bash completion code walk-through

Tags: bash, autocomplete

```
if [[ $COMP_CWORD -le $cmd_index ]]; then
        # The user has not specified a command yet
        local all_commands="$(tmux -q list-commands | cut -f 1 -d ' ')"
        COMPREPLY=( ${COMPREPLY[@]:-} $(compgen -W "${all_commands}" -- "${cur}") )
```

I am trying to understand above code snippet for tmux bash [autocompletion](https://superuser.com/questions/579545/how-to-tab-completion-when-typing-command-in-tmux)

compgen's W argument takes a word-list. But why does it taken an extra option `--` with the current word, `${cur}` as argument?

What does `:-` inside flower brackets mean?`${COMPREPLY[@]:-}`

When i do, `tmux<tab>`
the completion list displayed is same as `$(tmux -q list-commands | cut -f 1 -d ' ')`. 
So, why do we need `${COMPREPLY[@]:-}` in the array beginning?

Comment: ... because the `:-}` smiley looks awesome? Joke aside, the `--` likely is there to make it known that the next argument is not an option! My guess would be that Bash uses `getopt` internally, so it relies on [these conventions](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html)?!

Comment: `:-` is meant to remove the empty strings from inside the array.... So, need to understand what does double hypen mean as an argument to compgen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compgen -W "${all_commands}" -- "${cur}"` runs `compgen`, passing it:

- the option `-W` with one argument, the value of the variable `all_commands`;
- one non-option argument, the value of the variable `cur`.

The `--` argument marks the end of options. Even if the value of `cur` begins with a dash, it won't be interpreted as an option. This is an extremely common convention for command line option parsing.

`${COMPREPLY[@]:-}` is a weird one. It uses the [parameter expansion construct](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) `${VARIABLE:-TEXT}`, which expands to the value of `VARIABLE` if set and non-empty and to `TEXT` otherwise, in a mostly pointless way. It takes the elements of the array `COMPREPLY`, except that if the array is empty or undefined, it results in an empty string. Then [the result is split into words and each word is interpreted as a glob pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). This is exactly equivalent to `${COMPREPLY[@]}` except when `COMPREPLY` is not defined and `set -u` is in effect: under `set -u`, `${COMPREPLY[@]}` would trigger an error if `COMPREPLY` is not defined. Note in particular that this instruction does not append to the `COMPREPLY` array, it mangles it. To append to the array, the right code would be

```
COMPREPLY+=($(compgen -W "${all_commands}" -- "${cur}") )
```

assuming that the output of `compgen` contains a whitespace-delimited list of glob patterns.

Answer (score 0):

`Double hyphen` means the end of optional parameters and whatever follows hyphens need to be treated as positional parameters... read more @ [What does "--" (double-dash) mean? (also known as "bare double dash")](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash).

And `:-` is meant to remove the empty strings from inside the array...

all issues solved.. thanks...

Comment: No, `:-` does not remove the empty strings from the array. That's one of the consequences of using an unquoted variable expansion; `${COMPREPLY[@]}` would do it as well.