# Creating multiple nested directories with one command

Tags: mkdir

How can I create multiple nested directories in one command?

```
mkdir -p /just/one/dir
```

But I need to create multiple different nested directories...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`mkdir` accepts multiple path arguments:

```
mkdir -p -- a/foo b/bar a/baz
```

Comment: What does `--` mean?

Comment: @user3142695 End of options (e.g. `-s`/`--some-thing`) and only (positional) arguments from now on. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/117599
It's not strictly necessary here, I just added it to signify further that those are multiple positional arguments.

Answer (score 17):

To add to the above answers you can also do (in `csh`, `tcsh`, `ksh`, `bash`, `zsh`, `fish`, `yash -o brace-expand`):

```
mkdir -p /path/{to,a}/{lot,of}/directories
```

Comment: On `bash` and similar shells supporting that particular feature (_brace expansion_) that is. For more information, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace

Comment: @phk, you mean in `csh` and similar shells supporting that particular feature (that comes from `csh` (late 70s)).

Comment: Dash being the most common current shell that doesn't support it.  Bash, ZSH, and csh do.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Oops. BTW, does something like _caniuse.com_ for shells exist? (BTW, I should have added to my previous comment "For more information _on its implementation in `bash`_,")

Comment: `rc`/`es` don't support it either but have a _similar_ feature with `mkdir /path/^(to some)^/directories`

Answer (score 7):

Reading the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir) is always a good place to start.

The `-p` flag will create the required intermediate directories on the path.

Comment: You know even though it doesn't 'technically answer' the particular it's a very good point; you have to read the man pages as well as do - and type it out yourself helps you memorise it - if you really want to learn. Otherwise it's just a custom can of scripts for you (and in that case it may very well be a can of worms).

Comment: ...the man page (should) also tell you exactly how the implementation on the machine in front of you works - which may be different than the implementation of a random stranger from 5+ years ago