# What does `--` mean in the output of `declare -p`?

Tags: bash

```
$ declare -p ar
declare -a ar='()'


$ declare -p mmm
declare -- mmm="hello"
```

What does `--` mean here? Does it tell some attribute of `mmm`?

Thanks.

Comment: Read also [getopt_long(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt_long.3.html) which has a similar convention for `--` and also [GNU program arguments syntax conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's just there for consistency of output format; the first field is the literal `declare`; the second field is the attribute list; the third field is the `var=value`.

So for a variable with no specific attributes the command needs to have a way of showing "no attributes"; this is done with `--`

eg

```
bash-4.2$ declare y=100
bash-4.2$ declare -p y
declare -- y="100"
bash-4.2$ declare -l y
bash-4.2$ declare -p y
declare -l y="100"
bash-4.2$ declare +l y
bash-4.2$ declare -p y
declare -- y="100"
```

The result can be stored in a file and sourced in later.

Comment: Thanks. Are `declare -- y="100"` and `declare  y="100"` the same?

Comment: @Tim Yes, both have the exact same effect despite one having an aditional `--` .

Answer (score 1):

The double dash `--` declares the end of options for the given command. You'll find a very smart description by [cuonglm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/38906/cuonglm) by following [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash).

The given example shows how to grep for the value `-v` like this:

```
grep -- -v inputFile
```

So `-v` does not trigger the --invert-match option, but greps for the string `-v` inside the inputFile.

Answer (score 1):

`--` marks the end of options. It's superfluous here (since the variable name won't start with `-` (except for the pathological cases where the user's locale would be defined with `-` in the *alpha* character class) and anyway it's not added when there are flags) but harmless. I suppose it's there because the code had:

```
printf ("declare -%s ", i ? flags : "-");
```

Which was quicker to type than:

```
if (i)
  printf ("declare -%s ", i ? flags : "-");
else
  printf ("declare ");
```

Ironically, in `bash-2.01`, that code was changed to:

```
if (pattr == 0 || posixly_correct == 0)
  printf ("declare -%s ", i ? flags : "-");
else if (i)
  printf ("%s -%s ", this_command_name, flags);
else
  printf ("%s ", this_command_name);
```

To be reused for `export` and `readonly`, where that time the `--` was avoided for `export var=value` but not `declare -- var=value`.