# Scrips does not accept video ID starting with a hyphen

Tags: bash, youtube

I have tried two separate scripts for scrapping all comments of a Youtube video. 
Everything works fine, but there was one problem:Youtube video ID's starting with a hiphen, like `-FIHqoTcZog` does not work. 
I was wondering is there a way to escape every single character of that ID from shell interpretation, for instance using as an ID: `\-\F\I\H\q\o\T\c\Z\o\g`, but this did not work in my case.

The scripts i used was : [youtube-comment-downloader](https://github.com/egbertbouman/youtube-comment-downloader) and 
[youtube-comment-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-comment-scraper). Both require video ID. Even if that is surrounded by single or double quotes the ID works, but neither works if the video ID starts with a hyphen.

[Youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) had similar issue before, but now it accepts ID starting with hyphen: this is done by using the option `--id` , still it does not work in our case unless the hyphen is preceded by `--`, making the video name into `--id -- -FIHqoTcZog` when it is ok to be `--id xxxxxxxxxxx` in another case where the ID does not start with a hyphen.

Is there any way arround for my scripts to work with ID starting with a hyphen, like the way how it did in the [Youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/)'s case, or using another work arround?

Comment: Does `--id=-SoMeID` work?

Comment: @Kusalananda, that one is only a work around for Youtube-dl , and it is then for a hyphen starting ID: `--id -- -xxxxxxxx`, the two other scripts do not accept that form at all.

Comment: Since this is getting sent to an HTTP server, what about replacing the hyphen with "%2D"?

Comment: The `--id` option of `youtube-dl` doesn't do what you think: "_Use only video ID in **file name**_". That's why you still need to use `--`.

Comment: youtube-comment-downloader uses argparse. And @Kusalananda's answer (--youtubeid=-XXXX) should be accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Related question:** [What does “--” (double-dash) mean? (also known as “bare double dash”)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/243481)

---

The hyphen character is not interpreted by your shell but by the program/script (its parser, more precisely) you are using. That's why escaping it (at the shell level) doesn't work.

Programs often recognize arguments with leading hyphen(s) as **options**, not as **operands**. To interpret arguments like `-foo` as operands, programs usually follow one or more of these ways:

- Recognize the first `--` argument as the end of options marker: `program -- -foo`
- Let you pass operands as option-arguments: `program --option -foo`
- Recognize operands in alternative ways: `program prefix-foo`

In your specific scenario:

- `youtube-dl` accepts:

  - `-- -FIHqoTcZog`
  - `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FIHqoTcZog`
- `youtube-comment-downloader` seems to accept:

  - `--youtubeid -FIHqoTcZog`
- `youtube-comment-scraper` seems to accept:

  - `-- -FIHqoTcZog`
  - `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FIHqoTcZog`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found one solution to the script [youtube-comment-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-comment-scraper) after installing it again, suddenly , adding `--` in front of a video ID starting with `-` worked.
This hint is still not available in any of their documentation.
Now this works:
`youtube-comment-scraper --output OtherFile -f csv -- -FIHqoTcZog`

In the other script it still does not work yet.