# Stop executables and built-ins from interpreting a string argument starting with - as a switch?

Tags: shell, command-line, arguments, escape-characters, options

Let's say I want to search a file for a string that begins with a dash, say `"-something"`:

```
grep "-something" filename.txt
```

This throws an error, however, because `grep` and other executables, as well as built-ins, all want to treat this as a command-line switch that they don't recognize. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @Freddy Do all executables and built-ins accept `--`?

Comment: ErikE take it easy ... Maybe @Freddy haven't read my answer **yet**. Give it some minutes ....

Comment: @ErikE No, not all programs accept the `--`, there are exceptions (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash#comment470542_11382)). The `-e` switch is also mentioned in the [comments section](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash#comment299971_11382). I flagged this Q as duplicate, because I (still) think it is. You asked for a generic way and the `--` is a common way to handle such arguments. But that doesn't necessarily mean that this is the _only_ way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `grep` use `-e` to mark regex patterns:

```
grep -e "-something" filename.txt
```

For general built-ins use `--`,  in many utilities it marks "end of options" (but not in GNU grep).

Comment: `grep -- "-something" filename.txt` would have worked as well (due to GNU `grep`'s first synopsis form), but since there is a `-e` option for giving an expression, it might be better to use that.

Answer (score 2):

For `grep` you can also change the regexp so it doesn't actually begin with hyphen, by using a trivial character list:

```
 grep '[-]something'
```

This trick^Wmethod was traditionally used to avoid false matches in `ps`:

```
ps -f | grep myprog 
# lists both the process(es) running myprog AND the grep process
# making it harder to do things like choose the right process to kill(1)

ps -f | grep '[m]yprog'
# lists only the 'real' processes because [m]yprog matches "myprog" 
# but [m]yprog does NOT match "grep [m]yprog"
```

but in the modern era just using `pgrep` (or `pkill`) is easier.