# Error with rename command

Tags: rename, mv

I have an issue to rename the following file

```
-data-02-03-04.dat
```

I guess the issue come from the file name which starts with a dash. I get the following error trying to rename it.

```
rename -data-02-03-04.dat data020304.dat
Unknown option: data-02-03-04.dat
Usage:
    rename [ -h|-m|-V ] [ -v ] [ -0 ] [ -n ] [ -f ] [ -d ]
    [ -e|-E perlexpr]*|perlexpr [ files ]
```

Comment: Duplicate? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/117549

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem actually comes from the file name that starts with a dash, so it is taken as an option of the `rename` command rather than as an argument. To avoid the problem, just go through the path of the file:

```
mv ./-data-02-03-04.dat data020304.dat
```

I used the `mv` command which is more convenient to one single file. `rename` command is mostly used for batch renaming and requires a `perl` regular expression.

As pointed out [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean), another way to deal with the problem is to add a double dash `--`to signify the end of command options:

```
mv -- -data-02-03-04.dat data020304.dat
```

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to mention that `rename` is actually a custom alias for mv -v.

Comment: Actually no it can't be because the shell prompted you the usage of the `rename` command.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the -- , I wasn't understanding why I got errors like "rename: unknown option -- A" whereas I hadn't specified A as an option.   Ya saved me :)

Answer (score 0):

`rename` doesn't do what you think it does.

You could do one of the following:

```
mv ./-data-02-03-04.dat data020304.dat
```

```
mv -- -data-02-03-04.dat data020304.dat
```

If you really want to use rename, the correct syntax would be:

```
rename 's/-//g' ./-data-02-03-04.dat
```

```
rename 's/-//g' -- -data-02-03-04.dat
```

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to mention that `rename` is actually a custom alias for mv -v.

Comment: You may have attempted to implement that, but it’s not working — the error you posted is coming from the proper `rename`, not `mv`.