# Loop through all lines in a file and delete all files containing the line in their content

Tags: bash

We have a very manual and rudimentary email unsubscribe system that I am trying to automate. There is a file containing a list of the email addresses to unsubscribe, the format of this file is that there is one email address per line so cat should be able to be used I guess.

In the same folder, there are thousands of ".eml" files (raw email files) that are sent to sendmail in batch. Generating these .eml files is expensive so we keep them in a folder and send them periodically until a person unsubscribes. What I am trying to do is write a bash script looping through all the email addresses in the file, running grep on the folder for every email address, and deleting the file for which grep matches.

Since my Unix skills are very limited, I am trying to so as a reusable bash script (with loops and such) so that I get to improve my Unix skills

Comment: My reading of the question was that if `fooXXX.eml` *contains* `myaddress@domain.com`, it should be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. No, the name of the files are non descriptive and not helpful at all, the email addresses are in the content of the .eml files.

Comment: @NickD indeed, this is exactly this.

Comment: I suppose those `.eml` files are some sort of rfc822 format with header and body. And the email addresses are found in the To: or Cc: headers. Is the syntax consistent? For instance, is always in the To: header and with `<`, `>` brackets around the email address and on the same line as the `To:` prefix? Are email addresses potentially found elsewhere in the email (like email attachements containing forwarded emails, or in quoted parts or in From/Reply-to headers...)?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for your interest, the syntax of the headers is consistent. There are no brackets only the email address directly in the To field. Moreover email addresses can be find in a tracking image having the parameter "http://path...../image.png?fooparam=random@email.com".

Comment: Your question is similar to mine https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564239/how-to-remove-files-which-either-dont-contain-a-string-or-cant-be-opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive approach would be (assuming GNU utilities):

```
grep -FZlw -f address.list -- *.eml | xargs -r0 rm -f --
```

Or the same but with the long options as supported by GNU utilities:

```
grep --fixed-strings \
     --null --files-with-matches \
     --word-regexp \
     --file address.list \
     -- *.eml |
 xargs --no-run-if-empty --null \
   rm --force --
```

But that would delete files when addresses are found *anywhere* in the file, whether it's in the `From:`, `To:`, `Cc:`, `Reply-To` headers, or in the body of the email or in attachments.

Also if the `address.list` contains, `doe@example.com`, that would also delete emails for `john.doe@example.com` and `doe@example.com.eu`.

That also assumes email addresses are formatted the same (same case, no MIME encoding) in the `address.list` and in the `eml` files.

If you know exactly how the emails are formatted, for instance if they're always going to contain one and only one occurrence of a line like:

```
To: address@example.com
```

Where `address@example.com` is formatted exactly like in your `address.list`, then you can do:

```
sed 's/^/To: /' address.list | grep -xZFlf - -- *.eml | xargs -r0 rm -f --
```

Which would be more reliable.

Instead of passing the `address.list` as a list of *words* to be found anywhere in the files, we're transforming the search list first with the `s`tream `ed`itor command to prefix each line with `"To: "` so that the *fixed string* patterns become `To: address@example.com` and using `-x`/`--line-regexp` for those (instead of `-w`/`--word-regexp`) to match the full contents of lines e`x`actly. (so `To: address@example.com` doesn't match on `Reply-To: address@example.com.eu` for instance).

Replace `rm -f` with `grep -H '^To:'` above if instead of removing the files, you want to check what the `To:` header is for the files that are to be removed.

Comment: Thank you very much Stéphane, this is very helpful and instructive. Unfortunately I cannot upvote because I do not have enough reputation points, I have accepted the other answer because I was trying to create a reusable script using programming patterns that I would feel able to come out on my own next time. Your solution is very instructive, I will keep studying it and while at this minute using your solution would be using like using a piece of magic for me, which I am trying to avoid to learn, I hope to feel comfortable leveraging the power of these utilities and advance syntax soon.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer may also have given  some information for https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564239/how-to-remove-files-which-either-dont-contain-a-string-or-cant-be-opened

Comment: I ended up using this solution for performance reasons, we have tens of thousands of files and it looks like this solution only parses every file once which is ideal from a performance perspective. However I am wondering: what are the multiple "--" for ? (for grep and xargs)

Comment: I found my answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean

Comment: @Samuel, strictly speaking, the `--` is for `grep` and *`rm`*, not `xargs` here. See also my edit for some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

email_dir=./emails
unsubscribe_file=./emails/unsubscribe.txt

while IFS= read -r email _; do
    files=($(grep -rni "$email" "$email_dir" | grep -v 'unsubscribe.txt'))
    if ((${#files[@]}>1)); then
        printf '%s\n' "warning: Found multiple files for: $email" "${files[@]}" >&2
    elif ((${#files[@]}==1)); then
        rm "$(echo "${files[0]}" | awk -F\: '{print $1}')"
    fi
done < "$unsubscribe_file"
```

---

`email_dir` should be set to the path to the directory containing the emails
`unsubscribe_file` should be set to the path of the file containing the emails to be unsubscribed

The while loop will read through the unsubscribe file and for each line set the `email` variable to the first field (which should be the only field but `_` will catch anything leftover should it exist)

We will the grep within all files of the `email_dir` directory for that email address (which will also return the unsubscribe file so we are using grep to remove that from our results.  It would be ideal if that wasn't in the same directory.  **However be sure to change `grep -v 'unsubscribe.txt'` to reflect the actual name of your unsubscribe file**)

We set these results to an array in case there is more than one result.  In which case it will throw an error and remove nothing.  If there is only 1 result we will extract the filename from the grep output and remove it.

Comment: Thank you so much Jesse, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve, in light of your explanations I feel able to reproduce a similar solution on my own tomorrow, which I wouldn't feel able to do with a GNU utils solution using complex parameters. Thank you again this is so helpful

Comment: I am studying the code to learn, what is the underscore for in `IFS= read -r email _;` ? Also can you please break down the syntax #varName[@] if you have a couple of seconds, that would be very helpful to me

Comment: With read "The line is split into fields as with word splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME, the second word to the second NAME, and so on, with any leftover words assigned to the last NAME."  So in your case this shouldn't be an issue but say for example one of the lines in your unsubscribe file was `jesse@yahoo.com foobar baz`.  Without the underscore it would produce `email='jesse@yahoo.com foobar baz` with the underscore it would create `email=jesse@yahoo.com; _='foobar baz'`

Comment: `"${#files[@]}"` will print the length of the `files` array (number of elements).  This is documented in the bash manual under [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your time