# How to rename files according to names in a text file?

Tags: bash, rename

I have several files in a folder. I also have a csv file, containing the files name (without extension) listed in a specific order. I would like to rename the files in the folder to include the position in the list of the text file at the beginning of the file name.

In other words, my folder contains:

```
aaa.txt, bbb.txt, ccc.txt
```

The filename.csv contains:

```
ccc
aaa
bbb
```

What I want to obtain is:

```
1_ccc.txt, 2_aaa.txt 3_bbb.txt
```

Can I do this in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in *.txt
do line=$(grep -nx -m 1 -- "${i%%.*}" filename.csv | cut -f 1 -d ':')
name=${line}_${i}
mv -- "$i" "$name" 
done
```

**explanation**

`"${i%%.*}"`: As suggested by Kusalananda, takes the value of `$i`, strip off the pattern `.*` from the tail of the value (more info [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion))

`grep -nF --`

- `-x` matches whole line
- `-m 1` stop  reading  file  after 1 matching  line (to avoid `grep` to read all lines if the file is long)
- `--` is being used to signify the end of the options (more [-- in
  shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean/11378))
- `-n` returns line number instead of the line itself in following
  format

  `2:aaa
   3:bbb
   1:ccc`

`cut -f 1 -d ':'` extracts field 1 with `:` delimeter from the above result

Comment: `$(echo "$i" | cut -f 1 -d '.')` == `"${i%%.*}"`. Also, you need to double quote both `$i` and `$name`, and probably use `-e` with `grep` just in case the filename read (`$i`) contains `-` as its first character (and use `mv --` for the same reason).

Comment: thanks @Kusalananda! I really learn from your comments and answers.

Comment: Thank you both! I am going to try this . Just a curiosity: what will happen if the filename.csv contains also name of files wich are not present in this folder? Will they be skipped or cause an error?

Comment: @ginopino it will be skipped, I'm editing to make it perfect and also adding some details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to rename all files whose filename prefix is exactly a string in the CSV file, and that the filenames otherwise has a `.txt` filename suffix (and nothing else).

```sh
#!/bin/sh

suffix=txt

n=0
while IFS= read -r prefix; do
        n=$(( n + 1 ))

        name=$prefix.$suffix
        [ ! -e "$name" ] && [ ! -L "$name" ] && continue

        mv -- "$name" "${n}_$name"
done <filename.csv
```

This reads a line from the CSV into the variable `prefix` in each iteration of the `while` loop, and renames the file whose name is `$prefix.$suffix` (with `$suffix` being the static string `txt`) to `${n}_$prefix.$suffix`, where `n` is a variable whose value is a simple counter of how many lines have been read.

The `mv` command is only carried out if the source file exists.

No test is made for name collisions.

Answer (score 1):

awk could be an option too, this one handle spaces in the name also.

```
file='filename.csv'
find_path='/home/kali/test/'
extension='.txt'

awk -v find_path=$find_path -v extension=$extension \
'/^$/{NR=--NR; next} \
/^.+/ {print "mv -f " "\"" find_path $0 extension "\" " \
"\"" find_path NR "_" $0 extension "\"" \
}' $file | sh
```