# sed invalid option error for file names containing spaces

Tags: bash, sed, linux-mint

```
 BASE_NAME="$(basename "${1}")"
 FILE_NEW="$(echo "${BASE_NAME}" | sed -e "${REPLACE}")"
```

Here $1 refers to the file name that is passed to the function
The REPLACE Variable:

```
REPLACE='s/\[NOW\]/'${NOW}'/g;s/\[TODAY\]/'${TODAY}'/g;s/\[DATETIME\]/'${DATETIME}'/g;s/\[RANDOM\]/'${RANDOM_NUMBER}'/g;s/\[NAME\]/'${NAME}'/g;s/\[FILENAME\]/'${FILENAME}'/g'
```

What I want to do is modify the file names with the sed operator by replacing the above patterns. But when I come across a file which contains spaces followed by "-" and them something that gives a problem. For an example take to look at the following file names:

```
file -2.txt
file -3.txt
file -e.txt
```

In all those cases the errors thrown are as follows:

```
sed: invalid option -- '2'
sed: invalid option -- '3'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.'
```

If the file name just contans spaces and no "-" still there are problems:

```
file name.txt
```

would give the following error:

```
sed: can't read ./file: No such file or directory
sed: can't read name.txt: No such file or directory
```

The FULL CODE TO THE SCRIPT: [Full Script](https://gist.github.com/smooth-felix/0a71945164bf4ac3c7a134b8c82f31e9)

Comment: The `sed` command you give here is ok, but the one in the `replace_file_content` function is not, and is probably where the error is coming from. The problem (there and a number of other places in the script) is failing to double-quote variable references. Use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) to spot common mistakes like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error comes from the following line in the script:

```
sed -i $REPLACE $1
```

This is using both the `REPLACE` variable and `$1` unquoted, which means the shell will split these into words on spaces, tabs and newlines (and then additionally process these words for filename globbing patterns).  These words will then be given *as separate arguments* to `sed`.

You may get away with using

```
sed -i -e "$REPLACE" -- "$1"
```

You additionally have a couple of unquoted variables in your `clone_directory` function:

```bsh
  rename_file ${dir_name}
  ROOT=$FILE_NEW
  cd $ROOT
```

and also in your `replace_tags` function (note that using `{...}` around variable names is usually not needed and is *not* equivalent to quoting the variable).

Also note that shell options are not local to functions, so setting `extglob` in `get_file_folder_name` would set it globally.

See also:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376)
- https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Meta question: If the answer is "quote variables" then shouldn't the question be closed as duplicate of the questions you linked to anyway? Should or shouldn't we write the same answer over and over again?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Because there were other specific things I wanted to tell the user about too.