# perl `rename` script not working in some cases?

Tags: find, rename

I tried running the following command:

```
find . -type f -exec rename -v 's/ /_/g' {} \;
```

, to rename all files recursively with spaces in their names with underscores. The problem is that it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't work I get the following error:

```
Can't rename ./dir/subdir/file name with spaces ./dir/subdir/file_name_with_spaces: No such file or directory
```

Anything I could be doing wrong ?

Comment: Do any of your directories have a space? If so your code will replace those spaces too, resulting in a filename that doesn't exist

Comment: yes. That seems to be the case. Any way around this ? Also shouldn't the find `-type f` filter remove directories ?

Comment: See `man rename`, `--filename` option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is happening is that you are trying to run `rename` on a file in or below a *directory* with spaces in its name.  The `rename` utility is a bit simplistic by default and applies the given bit of Perl code to the complete argument, i.e. to the full pathname, not just to the filename portion of the pathname.

Fortunately, it's easy to restrict the action to the filename portion of the pathname:

```
find . -type f -execdir rename -v 'tr/ /_/' -- {} \;
```

The `-execdir` predicate is non-standard, but commonly implemented.  With `-execdir` in place of `-exec`, this executes the command with the directory where the file was found as its current directory.  This way the `rename` utility never sees the names of the file's parent directories.

I've used `--` here to protect against the event that we're trying to rename a file with a name starting with a dash (see [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376)). This would not be an issue with GNU `find` as the filenames will be prefixed with `./`, but this does not happen on at least some implementations of `find` on BSD systems.

Another option is to use the `rename` utility's `-d`, `--filename`, `--nopath`, or `--nofullpath` option (these are all the same):

```
find . -type f -exec rename -d -v 'tr/ /_/' {} +
```

This stops the utility from considering anything other than the filename portion of any given pathname argument.

I've taken the liberty to change the Perl expression from a `s///` command to a `tr///` command, since the transformation that we're performing is a simple transliteration and not a generic substitution.

You may also want to only run `rename` only on filenames that contain spaces. Pick these out with a `-name '* *'` test before the `-exec` or `-execdir`.

Comment: Alternatively, just use `rename`'s `-d` option (or the --long versions `--filename`, `--nopath`, `--nofullpath`) to prevent renaming directories - from the man page:  *"Do not rename directory: only rename filename component of path."*.   And use `{} +` with `find` instead of `{} \;` to minimise the number of times rename is executed by find.

Comment: @cas Thanks. I believe I'm using `-d` in the variant that does not use `--execdir`, but I seem to have left `{} \;` in place from the earlier variation. I will update that to use `{} +` as it makes more sense there.

Comment: sorry, i didn't notice you had `-d` (and all the aliases) in the second example. i kind of stopped reading in detail after the -execdir version.

Comment: @cas No worries! Thanks for poking at me regarding `{} +`.