# Do I ever need to use a ./ in the beginning of a relative log file path or a data file path?

Tags: linux, shell, filenames

Say I am running some command and redirecting its output to a log file with relative path. Three different examples:

1. `sh script.sh > logs/script1.log`
2. `./script2.sh &> logs/script2.log`
3. `./script3.sh input.txt > output.txt 2>logs/script3.err`

While is necessary to prefix `script2.sh` and `script3.sh` with `./` since the executable scripts are in the same directory but not in `${PATH}`, is it ever necessary (or preferable) to prefix the paths of the data files, whether input or output? If so, then the same three examples above would become:

1. `sh ./script.sh > ./logs/script1.log`
2. `./script2.sh &> ./logs/script2.log`
3. `./script3.sh ./input.txt > ./output.txt 2>./logs/script3.err`

In my testing the result is the same, but is it always so? Perhaps there would be a difference when symlinks are used ... I am not sure, hence this question.

I am working with code which sometimes includes `./` in front of the relative data (logs are data too) file paths and sometimes does not. There is no consensus among the team on the best practice and I would like to establish one. If `./` never matters in front of the relative data (as opposed to executable) file paths, then I'd prefer to never use it with non-executable file paths and if it sometimes makes a difference, then I suppose I should always prefix relative non-executable file paths with the `./`

What is the best approach?

Is there authoritative documentation for this by any chance?

Comment: `./` prefix will only be needed for executable file when `.` is not in `$PATH` (as should be the rule). prefixing date or log file with `./` is a matter of taste IMHO.

Comment: If there was `-input.txt` instead of `input.txt` then `./script3.sh ./-input.txt` would be safer in general. Compare: [double dash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618). Here the whole thing totally depends on how `script3.sh` parses/uses command line arguments and if it expects options (e.g. `-i`) like many tools do.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski Thank you, that is an interesting case. Granted, I would not name the files that I work with like so, but it is not always up to me what the files will be named.