# Bash function can't seem take in directories with spaces in them

Tags: shell-script

I created the following function is `~/.bashrc`:

```
function cl {cd $1; echo $1; ls -al $1}
```

(I put the echo command in there just to see what it's actually reading in)

In my home directory, I created a folder called "example folder", and I tried `cl "example folder"` and `cl example\ folder` and `cl ~/"example folder"`. All of them printed out the same thing:

```
-bash: cd: too many arguments
example folder
```

Followed by the ls command, which just lists out my current directory.

So, is there a way around this? How can I pass in a directory that contains spaces?

Comment: in short: double-quote your variables and positional parameters ($1, $2, etc)

Comment: @cas That's exactly it! I didn't even know that was a thing!

Answer (score 2):

```
function cl {cd $1; echo $1; ls -al $1}
```

is closer to zsh syntax than bash syntax, but even then, still has many issues.

In `bash`

- you need whitespace after `{`, and `}` to be preceded by a command delimiter (`;`, `&`, newline, though `)` would also do).  Doesn't apply to zsh.
- Parameter expansions must be quoted or otherwise they undergo split+glob. Doesn't apply to zsh.
- If you pass variable data to be meant to be a regular argument, not an option, you should make sure you precede it with the end-of-option marker (`--`) to avoid the data be taken as an option if it starts with `-`.
- you're not checking the exit status of `cd` after running the next command.
- `echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data. Use `printf` instead.
- after you have `cd`ed into `$1`, `ls -la $1` (or the more correct `ls -la -- "$1"`) won't work anymore if `$1` was a relative path. Most likely you want only `ls -la` (or `ls -lA`).
- In scripts, you generally want to use `cd` with `-P`, and after having made sure `$CDPATH` is unset or empty (`CDPATH= cd -P -- "$1"`) so that it behaves more like the `chdir()` of any other language. Does probably not  apply if the function is to be used from an interactive shell though.
- `function f { ...; }` is the ksh syntax for function definition. In `bash`, there's little reason to prefer that over the standard `f() { ...; }` syntax.

So:

```
cl() {
  cd -- "$1" || return
  printf '%s\n' "$1"
  ls -Al
}
```

Note that when not passed any argument, `cd` changes directory to your *home* directory (`cd` is like `cd ~` or `cd "$HOME"`).

However, here when `cl` is called with no argument `"$1"` expands to one empty argument instead of no argument at all (and `cd` would likely choke on that). To call `cd` with no argument if `cl` is called with no argument (so that `cl` alone brings you to your home directory and list the files there), you'd replace `"$1"` there with `${1+"$1"}`. Or you could call `cd` with the same list of arguments that `cl` received using `"$@"` so you can do for instance `cl -P ../bin` or `cl -- -dir-whose-name-starts-with-dash`.

Then, you'd likely want to print the current working directory after `cd` rather than the first argument with either `printf '%s\n' "$PWD"` or just `pwd`.

```
cl() {
  cd "$@" || return
  pwd
  ls -Al
}
```

More reading:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)
- [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590210)