# How to archive and compress large dataset into parts efficiently?

Tags: tar, split, lz4

Currently using following model, but one needs double the amount of disk space to restore compressed archive given one has to pipe all parts to tar before one can delete them.

```
$ COPYFILE_DISABLE=true tar \
  --create \
  --directory ~/data/dataset \
  --use-compress-program lz4 \
  --verbose \
  . | \
  split \
  --bytes 10G \
  --numeric-suffixes \
  - \
  dataset.tar.lz4.part
```

```
$ cat dataset.tar.lz4.part* | \
  tar \
  --extract \
  --directory ~/data/dataset \
  --use-compress-program lz4 \
  --verbose
```

Is there a more efficient model where parts can be deleted FIFO (first in first out) as they are decompressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do:

```
for part in dataset.tar.lz4.part*; do
  cat < "$part" || break
  rm -f -- "$part"
done |
  tar \
  --extract \
  --directory ~/data/dataset \
  --use-compress-program lz4 \
  --verbose
```

Don't use a `gz` suffix for `lz4`-compressed files, that would be misleading, `gz` is for `gzip`.

Comment: Thanks for helping out Stéphane! Does this model work for a 500GB dataset archived and compressed into 10G parts?

Comment: Also, is there a way to make model resilient to failure? My understanding is that if something goes wrong, one would have to download all deleted parts again, right?

Comment: Thanks for heads-up about `.gz`… fixed!

Comment: Curious why [--](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean) in this use case?

Comment: This is brilliant!

Comment: Why `cat < "$part" || break` vs `cat "$part" || break`?

Comment: @sunknudsen, replying to your questions in turn: (1) yes, there's no limit of size that I'm aware (2) to make it resilient and be able to resume an interrupted, you'd need separate archives, and delete them after successful extraction (3) `rm -f "$part"` would be incorrect in isolation, it would be OK here because we know from context that `$part` doesn't start with `-`, but I prefer showing the alwats correct `rm -f -- "$part"` variant. (4) see [When should I use input redirection?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/70756)

Comment: Thanks Stéphane!