# Check if a command exists revisited

Tags: raspberry-pi, posix

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7522866/9235421):  When I run `type -p` in the command prompt, it reliably tells me the path if the command exists:

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ type -p less
/usr/bin/less
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ type -p asdf
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

However, when used in a in a script it is as if the `-p` parameter is interpreted as a command of itself. It seems the `type` command ignores it as its option, because there is always some rogue text of `-p not found` in the result. It breaks the rest of the script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/sh

main() {
    for mycommand in $1; do
        echo Checking $mycommand
        loc="$(type -p "$mycommand")"
        echo $loc
        if ! [ -f "$loc" ]; then
            echo I think I am missing $mycommand
        fi
    done
}

main "less asdf"
```

Output of the script:

```
Checking less
-p: not found less is /usr/bin/less
I think I am missing less
Checking asdf
-p: not found asdf: not found
I think I am missing asdf
```

Can you please help me out here? Is there something about the shell on a raspberry pi that is causing this?

Comment: (1) Please get out of the habit of passing multiple arguments by passing a single string that contains multiple values, separated by whitespace.  (2) Please get into the habit of quoting shell variables: `"$1"`, `"$mycommand"`, `"$loc"`, etc.  (3) If you’re getting inconsistent behavior from shell builtin commands, perhaps you’re using different shells. Quite possible (probably?) your interactive shell is bash. `/usr/bin/sh` is probably *not* bash. Try writing the script with `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/usr/bin/bash`, or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as the first line.

Comment: Thanks for these tips. I just started learning bash, didn't know that there is much difference between sh and bash.

Comment: @Zababa, `sh` is a standard language for which there exist several interpreter implementations such as `bash`, `ksh` or `dash`, like C is a standard language for which there exist several compiler implementations such as gcc or clang (implementations of the `cc` standard command). bash supports extensions to that language, like gcc support extensions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`-p` is not a standard option for the `type` command¹. The `type` utility itself, though standard is optional in POSIX (only required on systems implementing XSI, though that is required to obtain UNIX compliance certification).

Instead of `type`, you can use `command -v` to check for availability of a command. No need to check its output, `command` will tell you via its exit status if it succeeded to find the command or not (regardless of whether it's an external command found in `$PATH`, a builtin or a function):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/sh -

main() {
    for mycommand do
        printf >&2 '%s\n' "Checking $mycommand"
        if ! command -v -- "$mycommand" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
            printf >&2 '%s\n' "I think I am missing $mycommand"
        fi
    done
}

main less asdf
```

`command` is a mandatory POSIX utility. The `-v` option to `command` used to be optional, but it's not any longer in the latest version of the POSIX specification.

Also remember that [`echo` can't be used to display arbitrary data](/q/65803), `--` must be used to separate options and non-options, errors (and in general diagnostics including progress/advisory information) should preferably go to stderr.

---

<sup>¹ it is however an option supported by the `type` builtin of the `bash`, `mksh`, `ksh93`, `busybox ash`, `zsh` and `yash` shells². In `mksh` and `yash`, it's meant to search the command in the standard `$PATH` (as returned by `getconf PATH` for instance), in `zsh`, it's for searching the command only in `$PATH`, not in aliases/builtins/functions. Same in `ksh93`, except that it also only prints the path of the found command. In `bash` (where it's used to be `-path`; still supported though no longer documented), `type -p` succeeds but prints nothing if the command is a builtin, and prints the path only like in ksh93 when it's an external command. In `busybox ash`, it behaves similarly to `command -v`</sup>

<sup>² all more or less conformant interpreter implementations of the standard `sh` language at least  when invoked as `sh`, though that doesn't prevent them from supporting extensions over that language in areas where the standard leaves the behaviour unspecified like here.</sup>

Comment: Why `command -v -- "$mycommand"` instead of `command -v "$mycommand"`? what's the meaning of `--` two dashes?

Comment: See [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
command="somecommand"
if [ "$(which "$command")" != "" ]; 
then
    echo "command found"
else
    echo "command not found"
fi
```