# Regular expressions using sed: what does `'1{/^$/d}'` do?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

While going through a shell script I came across the line

```
sed '1{/^$/d}' $file1 >> $file2
```

What is the significance of `sed '1{/^$/d}'` here?

Comment: While it removes `empty lines`  lines that are marked as `$` when running `sed -n l file1`  it won't remove lines that have `...spaces...`  in them. Therefore you could consider `sed '1{/^$/d;/\s*/d;}' file1`

Answer (score 5):

Remove line 1 if it's empty....

- `1{` - if we're on line 1
- `/^$/` - and it's an empty line
- `d` - delete the line
- `}` - end of condition

Example below.

```
$ cat x1

Hello
World
$ sed '1{/^$/d}' x1 >x2
$ cat x2
Hello
World
$
```

Answer (score 5):

The GNU `sed` expression

```
1{/^$/d}
```

which is more portably written

```
1{/^$/d;}
```

or

```
1 {
    /^$/ d
}
```

is in two parts:

1. `1 {...}`
2. `/^$/ d`

The first part triggers the command within braces if the current line is the first line of input.

The second part triggers the `d` command if the current line is empty, i.e. if the start of the line, `^`,  is immediately followed by the end of the line, `$`.  The `d` command discards the current input and immediately starts the next cycle (which means it skips to the following line of input and starts evaluating the expression from the very start).

Both `1` and `/^$/` are *addresses* that affect what lines the subsequent command will be applied to.

In short, your `sed` command deletes the first line of input if it's empty while avoiding deleting any other empty line.

The expression

```
/^$/ { 1 d; }
```

would have done the same thing but would require `sed` to perform a regular expression match on each line of input and would therefore potentially be more expensive (although it's questionable if you would notice any difference unless your input was huge and your computer very slow).

---

Apart from that, you should most likely quote the variables in your command, and the since we don't know what's in `$file1`, we'd better protect the command from accidentally interpreting the value as a set of options if it starts with a dash:

```bash
sed -- '1 { /^$/ d; }' "$file1" >>"$file2"
```

or,

```bash
sed -e '1 { /^$/ d; }' -- "$file1" >>"$file2"
```

or, make `sed` read from standard input,

```bash
sed '1 { /^$/ d; }' <"$file1" >>"$file2"
```

See also

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376)