# Why is using "|" or "&" provide different sizes of the result file?

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection, background-process

Here is my explanation:

1. `strings *.bin > bin.txt | sort -n bin.txt > logs1.txt`

   that gives me `logs1.txt`, but it has 621 KB.
2. `strings *.bin > bin.txt & sort -n bin.txt > logs1.txt`

   that gives me `logs1.txt`, but it has 0 KB.
3. `strings *.bin > bin.txt`
   `sort -n bin.txt > logs2.txt`

   these commands provide the file `logs2.txt` in 586,853 KB.

Note the `bin.txt` size is 586,853 KB, meaning just running the 3 options gives me the same size as the `bin.txt`, and I want to know the reason.

Answer (score 8):

Some of the details in this answer assume that the user uses a shell other than `zsh`. The details differ slightly for the `zsh` shell due to [its `MULTIOS` feature](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios).

1. `strings *.bin > bin.txt | sort -n bin.txt > logs1.txt`

   This runs `strings *.bin` and redirects the result to `bin.txt`.  At the same time as `strings` starts, `sort` is started and sorts the file `bin.txt`.  The pipe has no function at all in this pipeline other than allowing the two commands to run concurrently.

   Usually, the pipe is used to transfer the standard output of the left side's command to the standard input of the right side's command, but since both commands read from a file, the pipe is never used.

   Since both `strings` and `sort` are started concurrently, `sort` may possibly find the end of the `bin.txt` file before `strings` has finished writing the whole file. It's fairly random how much data `sort` will end up reading, if anything.

   Correct use of the pipe would have looked like

   ```bash
   strings -- *.bin | sort -n > logs1.txt
   ```

   Here, `strings` writes directly to the input of `sort` rather than to a file, and `sort` reads from the output of `strings` instead of from a file.

   The right-hand side of the pipe will be temporarily blocked if the left-hand side does not produce data fast enough, and the left-hand side will be temporarily blocked if the right-hand side can't consume the data fast enough. This way, the two utilities are *synchronized*, and you are guaranteed that `sort` will read the full output of `strings`.
2. `strings *.bin > bin.txt & sort -n bin.txt > logs1.txt`

   This suffers from the same issue as the previous command as both `strings` and `sort` are started concurrently.  The `&` starts `strings` in the background and `sort` is started immediately after that.  Both utilities write to or read from `bin.txt` independently of each other, and it's chance that decides how much of the file is written before `sort` reaches its end.
3. `strings *.bin > bin.txt` followed by `sort -n bin.txt > logs2.txt`.

   Here, you manually synchronize the two utilities by allowing `strings` to finish writing to the intermediate file `bin.txt` before using `sort` to sort its contents.  There is no issue, and you are guaranteed that `sort` will be able to read the complete output of `strings` from the file.

**Summary**: Your first two commands do not synchronize the `strings` and `sort` utilities. The writing by `strings` is independent of the reading by `sort`.  This means `sort` may find the end of the intermediate file before `strings` is finished writing all data. This, in turn, means you may get an incomplete end result. The amount of data your incomplete result will contain depends on chance.

The fact that the two utilities are started concurrently with each other also means that `sort` may even read a pre-existing `bin.txt` to the end before the shell even has time to truncate the file and start `strings`.

**Solution**: Write all data to the intermediate file first, then read from it, as in your third example.  Or, allow the two utilities to communicate the data directly between themselves using the pipe, as in my suggestion above:

```bash
strings -- *.bin | sort -n > logs1.txt
```

Or to keep a copy of the unsorted `strings` output for future reference:

```bash
strings -- *.bin | tee bin.txt | sort -n > logs1.txt
```

Further relevant reading here on U&L:

- [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)
- [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean)

Comment: re. "but since both commands read from a file, the pipe is never used.", also since the first command writes to a file. If it was just `sort foo.txt | sort bar.txt`, the pipe would still be written to, and if `foo.txt` as large enough, the pipeline would hang since nothing was reading from the pipe (small amounts of data would just disappear in the pipe buffers).